# Implementing Runnable in MainActivity

Tags: android

I have a very simply activity that prints a custom date time string to a textView. I implemented a runnable interface in the MainActivity it self and created a `Thread` at the end of `onCreate` method.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.run();
```

This is the run method

```
public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
                System.out.println(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

When i run it on the emulator i can see the System out in logcat. But the emulator shows ANR after about 5 seconds. What am i doing wrong. Is this method not suitable? is Async Task is the way to go here? I need to update the clock every second so is having a AsyncTask run forever is an acceptable pattern?

Comment: you need to call. `thread.start()`.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Implement a `CountDownTimer` ?

Comment: also, `localTime` is a `TextView` ?

Comment: @gunar yes and Ragu i called thread.run() is that what i did wrong?

Comment: Dude, you're blocking the UI thread ... the app is never breaking out of that look. That's why the ANR

Comment: yes i realize i should have called `.start()` not `.run()` thanks i fixed the problem

Comment: @DevZer0 if you did, you should have a crash on setText since you can't do it in other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the `thread.start()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

Quoting from the docs

There are two ways to execute code in a new thread. You can either subclass Thread and overriding its run() method, or construct a new Thread and pass a Runnable to the constructor. **In either case, the start() method must be called to actually execute the new Thread.**.

You are calling `thread.run()`. You are also calling sleep . You should not block the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

If you are looking for a count down timer

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

[Countdowntimer in minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620641/countdowntimer-in-minutes-and-seconds/17620827#17620827).

You can also use a Handler, timer task. If you use a timer task make sure you udate ui on the ui thread.

[Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725)

Edit: I failed to notice this. so from the above comments. Credits to DoctorDrive

```
    localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445()); // update ui from thread is not possible
```

You need to use `runOnUiThread`

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
             {
              public void run() 
              { 
                localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());

              }
             });
```

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, :-) i can't accept your answer yet i have to wait 7 minutes. thanks again much appriciated

Comment: @DevZer0 no problem its the rules of the forum. you have to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to update the clock every second so is having a AsyncTask run
>   forever is an acceptable pattern?

No, this is not recommended.  According to [AsyncTask Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), these should only run for short periods of time.  I would recommend you use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for this.

```
Timer timer;

public void onStart() {

    timer = new Timer();

    //this will update each second
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTask(), 0,1000);
}

class UpdateTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //update TextView
    }
}

public void onStop(){

    timer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
  System.out.println(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
}
}).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

probably you need to use thread.start() instead of thread.run()

thread.start creates a new thread and runs your code in a new thread.

thread.run runs your code in the parent thread, doesn't create a new thread

Answer (score 2):

It's because you call sleep in UI thread.
Don't ever call sleep in UI thread.
You can run stuff on UI thread using Handler.

```
private static final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    handler.postDelayed(textRunnable, 1000);
}

private final Runnable textRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
        System.out.println(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
    }
}
```

Or you can do it working, but the bad way

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        localTime.setText(LocalTime.getTime().format2445());
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```