# Updating textView with while loop?

Tags: java, android, while-loop, textview

I programmed a stopwatch but it works with java, but not on Android. If I press the Button it makes nothing. Could it be, that maybe Eclipse is wrong installed?

```
package com.example.stoppuhr;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    long start;
    long millis;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button start1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        start1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I think here is the problem.

```
        if (v.getId() == start1.getId()){
            textView1.setText("moldu");
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (true){
                millis = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;



                SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");//dd/MM/yyyy
                String ausgeben = sdfDate.format(millis);

                textView1.setText(ausgeben);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What did you mean by _but it works with java, but not on Android_?

Comment: I tried the same code with a normal java application with the difference: System.out.println and textview.setText

Comment: You're blocking UI thread ! Read about UI thread in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

Is a method that should be called when a button is clicked, but you have to register your class an OnClickListener for your button. You try to do this inside `onClick`.

So your class (`MainActivity`) will never be registered as an OnClickListener. Try moving this:

```
Button start1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
start1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

to `onCreate`.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your views in `onCreate`

```
Button start1,button2
TextView textView1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start1.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

You are also calling `Thread.sleep(30)` on the ui thread. This will block the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Quoting from the docs

If you implement `Thread` or `HandlerThread`, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—**do not call** `Thread.wait()` or `Thread.sleep()`.

Make sure you do not call `Thread.sleep()` on the ui thread.

I suggest you have a look at the count down timer.

1. [Android Thread for a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839419/android-thread-for-a-timer/17839725#17839725)
2. [Countdowntimer in minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620641/countdowntimer-in-minutes-and-seconds/17620827#17620827)

`public static void sleep (long time)` // in milliseconds

> Added in API level 1 Causes the thread which sent this message to
>   sleep for the given interval of time (given in milliseconds). The
>   precision is not guaranteed - the Thread may sleep more or less than
>   requested.
>
> Parameters time   The time to sleep in milliseconds. Throws
>   InterruptedException  if interrupt() was called for this Thread while
>   it was sleeping See Also interrupt()

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do: `addOnClickListener()`, you can read about it. I'd google it to understand how it works.

If you added this to your button, by using

```
Button buttonname = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);
buttonname.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in your `onCreate()` method, you successfully added the `onClickListener()` to the button.
If this button is pressed now, the `onClick()` will be called.