# Timer for an editText Box : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am trying to make the edittext boxvibrate and change color momentarily if a wrong password is entered

```
final Drawable oldBackground = findViewById(R.id.email).getBackground();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivty.this.findViewById(R.id.password).setBackground(oldBackground);
        MainActivty.this.findViewById(R.id.email).setBackground(oldBackground);
    }
};


Toast.makeText(MainActivty.this , valArray.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
findViewById(R.id.password).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
findViewById(R.id.email).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timer task runs on a different thread. Ui should be update on the ui thread.

Use `runOnUiThread` or use a `Handler`.

```
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run(){
               // update ui here  
              }
           });
```

Handler

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something  
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

You can also use a CountDown timer

[Countdowntimer in minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620641/countdowntimer-in-minutes-and-seconds/17620827#17620827)

Comment: how would i call this

Comment: put the `runOnUithread` part inside the timer task. or use a handler or use a count down timer.

Answer (score 5):

you must use **Timer** by **runOnUiThread** Method Like This:

```
final TextView lblSSID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblWifiSSID);
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lblSSID.setText(networkConnection.getWifiName());
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```