# Countdown using CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, counter

I have a countdown timer. The countdown timer counts down in miliseconds. I have worked out hours by using the sum:

```
(((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) / 60)
```

Now minutes, I did this today and I seriously can not see how minutes works, but it does, here is what I have done for minutes...

```
long minsTotal = hoursS * 60;
(((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60) - minsTotal)
```

Now when I typed that in to a caluculator it awlays equated to 0... But somehow it works....

Now the seconds is where i'm stuck. To work out the seconds I have used:

```
long secs = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
```

which works out the total seconds. However I want the highest number for it to display as 60. How could I stop if from going over 60, but still working properly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620641/countdowntimer-in-minutes-and-seconds/17620827#17620827 check this if it helps

Comment: Or maybe you could use long secsMod60 = secs % 60;