# how to set timer in format HH:MM:SS to textview by difference time in android?

Tags: android, datetime, timer, textview

I have current date in format "**2014-05-14T16:23:11.810Z**" and Counter date is "**2014-05-15T16:24:13.810Z**"

I want to display the counter time in between those dates in **HH:MM:SS i.e 24:01:02** in TextView 
      which update continuously by 1 sec. Like timer

but how to calculate the difference between these two dates and convert it into **HH:MM:SS**

I writting simple code which countdown timer shows in milliseconds in android :

```
CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtNewBetTimer.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txtNewBetTimer.setText("Time Up");
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

I want output like this :

[image]

Please anyone help me for this ...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620641/countdowntimer-in-minutes-and-seconds/17620827#17620827. check this if it helps

Comment: this is helpful but how to set the hours ,it only set min sec

Comment: convert milliseconds to hours

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        txtNewBetTimer.setText(""+String.format("%d:%d:%d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
        toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
   }

   public void onFinish() {
        txtNewBetTimer.setText("Time Up");
   }
};
timer.start();

Alternative way

CountDownTimer timer=new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
         int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
         int hours   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
         txtNewBetTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%d:%d",hours,minutes,seconds));
   }
   public void onFinish() {
         txtNewBetTimer.setText("Time Up");
   }
};
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(); 

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    date.setTime(millisUntilFinished);
    textView.setText(sdf.format(date));
}
```

Comment: i assume there may be needed to add time offset e..g 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

You can code it yourself or use the provided utility method [`DateUtils.formatElapsedTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime%28java.lang.StringBuilder,%20long%29).