# how to use timer in minutes and seconds

Tags: android, timer, textview, timertask

I am using a Timer in my android app.

This is what i am using,

```
Timer t = new Timer();
 //Set the schedule function and rate
 t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

      public void run() 
     {
         //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() 
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                    time += 1;

                }

            });
     }

 },
 //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
 0,
 //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
 1000);
```

In my code, there's only `seconds` as you can see But I want it in Minutes and seconds like `00:01`.

So, how to do it. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may find this post useful.-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format

Comment: @ssantos how to implement that in this code. Can you provide me some code. I have to use this timer in my whole activity and in last in another activity i will show total time taken

Comment: Just provided an answer with example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach to obtain the `String` you're looking for, would look like.-

```
int seconds = time % 60;
int minutes = time / 60;
String stringTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
tv.setText(stringTime);
```

If you need to show the results only in your second `Activity`, I'd recommend passing time value into args bundle, and generate the `String` from the activity which will display it.

Comment: yeah! :) Its the same what I need