# cant convert song duration from ms to a format h:m:s

Tags: java, android

i have developed a code that retrieves songs from sdcard but my problem is am recieving song duration im milliseconds. i want to convert it to a format h:m:s. but have failed.
here is my code`

```
public class SongsActivity extends ListActivity {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
    private Utilities utils;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.dura);

        String[] from = {
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};
        int[] to = {
            R.id.title, R.id.artist, R.id.album, R.id.dura};


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.custom_list_item, cursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

any one please help me show me how i can change MediaStore.Media.Duratio from milliseconds to H:M:S. thank you in advance for your help

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

Comment: a SimpleCursorAdapter won't be sufficient for that. You'll need to override some parts of `bindView` or `getView`

Answer (score 3):

A trivial `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime`:

```
DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(timeInMillis);
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the duration in milli seconds **`(ms)`**

```
String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d", 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(ms),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms) -  
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(ms)), 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(ms) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(ms)));
```

The above code will convert it to **`HH : MM : SS`** (note `%02d` to specify the number of digits)