# Difference between two Calendar times. One hour more in result

Tags: java, date, time, difference, milliseconds

I have 2 times in calendar.

```
    Calendar orarioP1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 3, 28, 8, 30, 00);
    Calendar orarioA1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 3, 28, 12, 35, 06);
```

I implemented this function for get the time difference but it return me +1hour difference.
I need to return the correct difference `4:05:06` but now it return me `5:05:06`. Can anyone help me?

```
public String getTimeDiff() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss");
    long milliSec1 = orarioP1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milliSec2 = orarioA1.getTimeInMillis();

    long timeDifInMilliSec;
    if(milliSec1 >= milliSec2) {
        timeDifInMilliSec = milliSec1 - milliSec2;
    } else {
        timeDifInMilliSec = milliSec2 - milliSec1;
    }

    long timeDifSeconds = timeDifInMilliSec / 1000;
    long timeDifMinutes = timeDifInMilliSec / (60 * 1000);
    long timeDifHours = timeDifInMilliSec / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    long timeDifDays = timeDifInMilliSec / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    Date date = new Date(timeDifSeconds);
    String difference = sdf.format(date);

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: These things are almost always a result of Daylight Saving Time or a timezone difference. A quick look [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2014.html) shows us that this date is indeed around the time DST sprung into action.

Comment: [This approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9027379/256196) may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: Tip: (A) Learn about [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library with its Duration, Interval, and Period classes to handle a span of time. The new java.time package in Java 8 may have similar. (B) Always specify your intended time zone in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You craete a Date 1970-01-01 04:05:06 GMT and it gets shifted to your current timezone. Either format time difference on your own ore better use Joda Time library.

Use `Period` class from Joda Time. [Docs here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html)

Your code:

```
   public String getTimeDiff() {
      DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 3, 28, 8, 30, 00);
      DateTime end = new DateTime(2014, 3, 28, 12, 35, 06);
      Period period = new Period(start, end);
      return PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(period);
  }
```

Returns: `4 hours, 5 minutes and 6 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding it.
`new Date(long timemillisec)` will return a Date instance of `since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT + your timemillisec`.

It is your time zone which is making `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00` to somewhat nearly `January 1, 1970, 05:~:~`

just use :

```
String difference = sdf.format(new Date(0));
```

you will get the same result i.e. 1 hour difference in your case, it is due to time difference from GMT.

And have a look at your code, you are converting milliseconds to seconds, you don't need that.

just use millisecs : `Date date = new Date(timeDifInMilliSec);`

have a look at this :

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd h:mm:ss");
 System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1000)));
```

**Output**

```
1970/Jan/01 5:30:00
1970/Jan/01 5:30:01
```

It is for my location.

Comment: i tried to change 
String difference = sdf.format(date);
to
String difference = sdf.format(new Date(0));
but it give me other result different from the real result!

Comment: First you have to correct your error. In your code you must take `timeDifInMilliSec` instead of `timeDifSec`. your code is returning you `sdf.format(new Date(0).getTime() + timeDifInMilliSec)` @MarcC

Comment: i changed timeDifSec to timeDifInMillisec and changed sdf.format(date) to sdf.format(new Date(0)) but it return me 1:00:00, not the correct value 4:05:06 @afzalex

Comment: You must be kidding. `1:00:00` can only be returned if your GMT time zone difference is 0.@MarcC . I am editting my answer and adding outputs from my place.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    Calendar orarioP1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 3, 28, 8, 30, 00);
    orarioP1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Calendar orarioA1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 3, 28, 12, 35, 06);
    orarioA1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println("Difference In Hours : "
       +(orarioA1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)-orarioP1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
    System.out.println("Difference In Minutes : "
        +(orarioA1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)-orarioP1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    System.out.println("Difference In Seconds : "
        +(orarioA1.get(Calendar.SECOND)-orarioP1.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
    System.out.println("Difference In MiliSeconds : "
       +(orarioA1.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)-orarioP1.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)));
```