# Count down timer show wrong values : Android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm using `CountDownTimer` in my Application and it's showing wrong hours.
this is what i tried.

```
long miliSecsDate = milliseconds ("2017-11-18 12:35");
```

**Convert date and time in to miliseconds**

```
public long milliseconds(String date)
            {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                try
                {
                    Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
                    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                    return timeInMilliseconds;
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

Countdown timer

```
public void showCountdown(long miliSecsDate){
        new CountDownTimer(miliSecsDate, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

                int minutes = (int)(seconds % 3600) / 60;
                int hours = (int)seconds / 3600;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                Log.d("time",""+hours+" : "+minutes+" : "+seconds);
          }
            public void onFinish() {
                txtRemainingTime.setText("done!");
            }

        }.start();
    }
```

my Log cat showing like below

`D/time: 419719 : 3 : 43`

Comment: What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: today is 2017-11-17 hours should around 24.but it's return 419719 hours

Comment: It returns the number of hours since 1970-01-01

Comment: If you want to like it should return around 24 hours. Then make the difference of current time from that and start implementing.

Comment: @NigamPatro How can i change current time?

Comment: @user8164155 changing current time means?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
    String myDate = "2017-11-18 12:35";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
    long millis = date.getTime();

    long seconds = millis/1000;
    long sec = seconds % 60;
    long min = (seconds / 60) % 60;
    long hrs = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;


    Log.d("time",""+hrs+" : "+min+" : "+sec);
```

If you want to use `TimeUnit` class [Refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

Comment: still same result return 7 hours

Comment: can you show the `date in String` and also its `millisecond` value?

Comment: this is my log ` D/time:  Sat Nov 18 12:35:00 GMT+05:30 2017 Miliseconds 1510988700000 `