# Android CountDown Timer : Add Hour

Tags: java, android

Add Hours in Count Down Timer , i have only minutes then how to format it

```
 private void updateCountDownText() {
        int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 36000;
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the format shown is just like 2 hours , 00:119:44

Comment: fixed already Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds to "hh:mm:ss" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

Comment: Thanks Sir @Micer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `TimeUnit` instead of manually converting time.

Try this:

```
int hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(mTimeLeftInMillis);
int minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mTimeLeftInMillis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1);
int seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mTimeLeftInMillis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1);

String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
```