# How to get milliseconds in time?

Tags: java, time, libgdx

I'm trying to add milliseconds in my String, actually I'm using this:

```
time.update(String.format(textFormat, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis), millis);

textFormat = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
```

The result I want is like this:

[image: image of desired result]

But I get this:

[image: image of actual result]

What should I do? Can I get this using maths?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. For instance, what is `MILLISECONDS`?

Comment: TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS

Comment: Please search for [java format duration] or similar. This has been answered with variations quite a number of times already. I’m immodest enough to recommend [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50438972/5772882).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value should be reduced modulo 1000, since you want milliseconds past the last complete second.

```
millis % 1000
```

And then you'll want %03d, on account of there being 1000 milliseconds in a second.

If you really only want two digits, that's centiseconds, not milliseconds, so use

(millis % 1000) / 10