# How to not exceeding 60 second with java timer

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8

I am using java timer, but my problem is every time exceeding 60 seconds, I like my code working like;

1 minutes 59 seconds,
2 minutes 0 seconds..

My code is below.

```
private long lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${listenScheduled}", initialDelay = 1000)
private void distanceBetweenLastReceivedMessageAndCurrentTime() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastReceivedMessage;
    logger.info("has threw 'INFO' event due to is not running as an expected since {} {} {} {} ", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(currentTime), "minutes", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentTime), "seconds");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert milliseconds to "hh:mm:ss" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time* classes

Capture the current moment using `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant then = Instant.now() ;
…
Duration d = Duration.between( then , Instant.now() ) ;
String output = d.toString() ;
```

The `toString` method generates text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMn`. I suggest you report using that format. The format uses a `P` to mark the beginning. A `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds. So, two and a half minutes is `PT2M30S`.

If you insist on your format, call the `to…Part` methods on `Duration`.

Comment: @johndeltana  - This is indeed the idiomatic way of solving your problem. Just keep in mind that `Duration` gives a directed value i.e. a duration may be negative. Also, the `to...Part` was introduced with Java-9 (not with Java-8 which introduced `java.time` API). Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to automatically separate the minutes and seconds. Also, I would recommend breaking up that `logger.info` statement for readability.

One way to do it is to convert it to seconds first, set the modulus (remainder) of the seconds and 60 as your `seconds`, then divide the minutes for the `minutes` value. Or you could just skip the conversion and divide + modulus by 60000.

```
long msElapsed = 660_000; //5min 30sec

long secElapsed = msElapsed / 1000;

long minutes = secElapsed / (long) 60;

long seconds = secElapsed % 60;

System.out.printf("%d %d",(int)minutes,(int)seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer its giving output like this;11 011 011 011 011 02021-07-01 17:39:38.520 DEBUG 5832 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1]

Comment: currentTime /lastReceivedMessage + 60000, "seconds" did you mean that