# How to convert the seconds in this format "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, android, time

I want to convert the second/milliseconds in this format "HH:mm:ss" (for esamples, from 5 seconds to 00:00:05). I tried to get that format in this way:

```
int millis = 5000;
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = df.format(millis);
```

In that way, I get "01:00:05" and not "00:00:05". Where am I wrong?

Comment: This question has better answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/625624/685806) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/266970/685806).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Milliseconds to "X mins, x seconds" in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert time in seconds to HH:MM:SS format in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911455/how-to-convert-time-in-seconds-to-hhmmss-format-in-mysql)

Answer (score 24):

Timezones.

The long value `5000` means 5 seconds after the epoch.  For the majority of timezones, 5 seconds after the epoch is not 5 seconds past midnight local time.

**Java 8 update**:

`java.time.LocalTime` will handle the idea of a wall-clock "time of day" without you having to worry about the timezones and days implicit in `java.util.Date`.  If you can use Java 8, and your durations will always be less than a day, then a correct version of your example can be as simple as:

```
int millis = 5000;
int seconds = millis / 1000; // Maybe no need to divide if the input is in seconds
LocalTime timeOfDay = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(seconds);
String time = timeOfDay.toString();
```

(I guess strictly speaking, `java.time.Duration` is a better *model* of what you want, in that it represents a certain number of seconds, rather than a time-of-day.  But it's a pain to format into hh:mm:ss, so if you're always dealing with sub-24hour values, TimeOfDay gives you this formatting for free and is otherwise equivalent.)

---

If you're stuck with Java 7 or below, then explicitly specifying a timezone of `GMT` in your example code should give you the output you expect.

Here's a Scala REPL session demonstrating the problem, and Java 7 solution, on my machine:

```
scala> val millis = 5000
millis: Int = 5000

scala> val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
df: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@8140d380

scala> df.format(millis)
res0: java.lang.String = 01:00:05

scala> df.getTimeZone.getID
res1: java.lang.String = GB

scala> df.getTimeZone.getOffset(millis)
res2: Int = 3600000

scala> df.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))

scala> df.format(millis)
res3: java.lang.String = 00:00:05
```

So you can see that my default time zone is `GB`, which has a 1 hour offset from GMT at the time denoted by `5000L`.  Setting the timezone to GMT gievs the expected output of `00:00:05`.

Comment: Are you sure this is timezone related?  I'm in the GMT timezone, and calling `df.getTimeZone()` in the above code returns `id="Europe/London"` and I get the same output of "01:00:05".

Comment: Yep, London was 1 hour ahead of GMT at the time in question (according to Java at least).  See my edit for a worked example.

Comment: It's works. I added this `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: Just to add that if you have more than 24h, the hours will show only the remainder (e.g. for 34h, it will return 10:00:00). I haven't found a solution to include days as well (using ``DD`` starts the count from 1, so 34h would be 02:10:00:00, instead of 01:10:00:00), or to show more than 24 hours (e.g. 34:00:00).

Comment: in most cases probably not very important but the LocalTime solution also seems to be faster than using SimpleDateFormat. I got 100 ms instead of 350 for one million runs

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a simple utility function for this task which does not require any Java version nor instantiates any unnecessary objects:

```
/**
 * provides a String representation of the given time
 * @return {@code millis} in hh:mm:ss format
 */
public static final String formatTime(long millis) {
    long secs = millis / 1000;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", secs / 3600, (secs % 3600) / 60, secs % 60);
}
```

Unlike some other solutions here, this can even deal with up to 100 hours

Answer (score 16):

I got this to work.  Let me know if it works for you.  Seems like a lot of lines to do something seemingly simple..

```
    int millis = 5000;
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    String time = df.format(new Date(millis));
    System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: this worked for me too.
if anyone finds a better way, please let me know.


p.s its good to know that java is still lacking simple Date/Time functionality.

Comment: @APT - You may be sad to learn that Java 8 does have much better Date/Time functionality(!).  I've updated my answer with an example using the new `java.time` package.

Answer (score 5):

You should get SimpleDateFormat with Locale argument.

```
public static String getDateFromMillis(long millis) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    return formatter.format(new Date(millis));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new Date every time. formatter.format(millis); will also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HHMMSS {

        final int UUR = 3600;
        final int MINUUT = 60;

    public void converteerTijd() {

        int uren, minuten, seconden, ingave;
        System.out.print("Geef een aantal seconden: ");
        ingave = Input.readInt();
        uren = ingave / UUR;
        minuten = (ingave - uren * UUR) / MINUUT;
        seconden = ingave - uren * UUR - minuten * MINUUT;
        String nU1 = (uren < 10) ? "0" : "";
        String nM1 = (minuten < 10) ? "0" : "";
        String nS1 = (seconden < 10) ? "0" : "";
        System.out.println(nU1 + uren + "-" + nM1 + minuten + "-" + nS1 + seconden);
```

Comment: Put brief description what kind of issue you are facing.

Comment: Not the most polished answer ... but it works really well.

Comment: Using String.format, this could be done far nicer, similar to [Oles Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43368279/6723250), even without Java 9

Answer (score 1):

Java 9 answer:

```
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMillis(millis);
    System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                       dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart(), dur.toSecondsPart()));
```

(not tested yet)

The `toXxPart` methods are described in [the API docs for Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

Answer (score 0):

This example has no localization warning:

```
public static String getTime(int sek) {
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d", sek/3600, (sek%3600)/60, sek%60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Show time duration like YouTube**

```
String duration(int length){
    String format =String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d:%02d", length/3600, (length%3600)/60, length%60);
    if (format.length()>=7 && format.startsWith("00:0"))
        format=format.replace("00:0","");
    if (format.length()>=7 && format.startsWith("00:"))
        format=format.replace("00:","");
    Log.d("seeformat",format);
    return format;
}
```