# How to convert time in seconds to HH:MM:SS format in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm having a data column named **test_duration bigint(12)**. I'm storing time in seconds into the database. Now when I fetch record from the table I want the time converted into HH:MM:SS format. How should I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use **MySQL** function [SEC_TO_TIME()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sec_to_time-function.php).

Example:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(2378);
```

Output is:

```
00:39:38
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(test_duration) as `Time` FORM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you store the time in Unixtime (Unix seconds?).
If so, use:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, '%h:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a MYSQL function that transform seconds to the format "HH:MM:SS":

```
SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)
```

Example:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(3661);
```

will output:

01:01:01

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The max value that you can get from the function SEC_TO_TIME is 838:59:59

If you have bigger number you can use this code:

```
SELECT DAY, Floor((SUM(DAY) / (60*60))) AS Hours, 
Floor(MOD(SUM(DAY), (60*60)) / 60) AS Minutes, 
Floor(MOD(SUM(DAY), (60))) AS Secs,

CONCAT(
    Floor((SUM(DAY) / (60*60))), ":", 
    Floor(MOD(SUM(DAY), (60*60)) / 60), ":", 
    Floor(MOD(SUM(DAY), (60)))
) AS Time

FROM (SELECT 5328089 as DAY) a
```