# convert to hours and sum the hours worked mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column name duration with time in seconds for example i have 28000 seconds now i want to convert the second to hours and sum total number of hours for a users i have list of users with hours works which is stored in seconds like 28000 here my query

```
SELECT ohrm_project.project_id AS ohrmprojectid, ohrm_project.customer_id, 
       ohrm_project.name AS ohrm_projectname, 
       ohrm_timesheet_item.duration AS duration,
       ohrm_timesheet_item.date AS date, 
       TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(ohrm_timesheet_item.duration),"%Hh %im")) as totalhoursworked,
       hs_hr_employee.* 
FROM ohrm_project,ohrm_timesheet_item,hs_hr_employee 
WHERE ohrm_timesheet_item.employee_id=hs_hr_employee.employee_id AND 
      ohrm_timesheet_item.project_id=ohrm_project.project_id AND 
      ohrm_project.project_id=2 AND 
      ohrm_timesheet_item.date BETWEEN '2016-03-31' AND '2016-04-06'
```

[image]

I tried query but i am getting total hours worked but i am not getting in correct i want to get suppose i have two user i want to get total hours work for 1st person and total hours for second user but i am getting only 1 user with total hours of users like this i am passing my screenshot see

Comment: Check these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911455/how-to-convert-time-in-seconds-to-hhmmss-format-in-mysql and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193868/convert-seconds-to-human-readable-time-duration

Comment: convert seconds to hours  is working has you have the links but the problem  i need to sum the total hours for every users

Comment: Do you want to code in MySql? I can only give you the logic: SUM the seconds of users then convert to hours.

Comment: Yes i want query in mysql

Comment: I am not good at MySql but something like this TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ohrm_timesheet_item.duration)),"%Hh %im")

Comment: let me check your logic

Comment: I tried your query but i am getting total hours worked but i am not getting in correct i want to get  suppose i have two user i want to get total hours work for 1st person and total hours for second user but i am getting only 1 user with total hours of  users like this i am passing my screenshot see

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY {userid}` in order to get the values for each user.