# SQL query - converting seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, time

I have the following query that returns a total seconds value (up to 86400 seconds (1 day))

I want to convert this to an HH:MM:SS value. Any help is appreciated.

```
(SELECT FIRST TSS.TotalDrivingTime 
 FROM HLG01_TR_TachographShiftSummary TSS
 WHERE TSS.DriverID = TRD.DriverID
   AND (CONVERT(date, TSS.PeriodStart)) = S.LoadDate)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a date in YYYY-MM-DD format from a TSQL datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889629/how-to-get-a-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format-from-a-tsql-datetime-field)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `cast(TSS.TotalDrivingTime as interval hour to second(0))` - the ANSI SQL way!

Answer (score 0):

in sqlserver you can use:

```
declare @Seconds as int = 86400; SELECT CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(SECOND, @Seconds, 0)) as 'hh:mm:ss'
```

and in mysql

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(test_duration) as `Time` FORM YOUR_TABLE;
```

or

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, '%h:%i:%s')
```

[How to convert time in seconds to HH:MM:SS format in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911455/how-to-convert-time-in-seconds-to-hhmmss-format-in-mysql)

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/reply/1459738

Comment: This SELECT clause is a sub-query embedded in a larger query. I'm struggling to get the syntax exactly correct. I've tried:-

(CONVERT(time(0), DATEADD(SECOND,SELECT FIRST TSS.TotalDrivingTime FROM HLG01_TR_TachographShiftSummary TSS WHERE TSS.DriverID = TRD.DriverID AND (CONVERT(date, TSS.PeriodStart))= S.LoadDate)) AS 'hh:mm:ss',

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
(Format(Int(Sum([Seconds])/3600),'00') & ':' & Format(Sum([Seconds]/86400),'nn:ss')) AS [Total Time]
```