# Android countdown, is this the correct way?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I got this. But i can't seem to work out how to get the number of days/hours/minutes/seconds left. I ran it in debug mode and it produced: 2776799998. 2776799998 in milliseconds is way to much for 2 days, 1 hour and 15 minutes. (Was when posting this).

What is the correct way?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2012, 6, 28, 16, 0);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long remaining = endTime - currentTime;

long seconds = remaining / 1000;
long minutes = seconds / 60;
long hours = minutes / 60;
long days = hours / 24;
```

Comment: It is about 32 days. Your month is 1 ahead - try using 5.

Comment: What is your minSDKVersion? Use TimeUnit if possible. Your seconds calculation should use mod instead of division. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Calendar's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Answer (score 4):

The [month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) on the Calendar API starts in 0. So 6 corresponds to July. Maybe that's your problem.