# Find difference between two time in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Milliseconds to “X mins, x seconds” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java)
>   [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

I have a function like this:

```
 public String setDateAndTime(int h, int m, int s,int amPm) {
    TimeZone nst = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:45");
    Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar(nst);
    Date currentTime1 = new Date();
    calendar1.setTime(currentTime1);


    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, s);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    calendar1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, amPm);


    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String date = formatter.format(calendar1.getTime());

    return date;
}
```

Through this function i created two dates(String)

```
String s1=setDateAndTime(12,00,00,1);//12:00:00 PM
String s2=setDateAndTime(3,15,45,0);//3:15:45 AM
```

Now how to find to find difference between s1 and s2, i also need the hours, minutes and second lefts, so that i can do further processing.

Comment: Did you search on SO?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: I would start by making your function return a Date type, not a string

Comment: @BrianAgnew i need to display those times in a jsp page, so i used String instead of date.

Comment: Why don't you convert your time string into milliseconds, calculate your difference and convert it into a time string back?

Comment: @Binay you should only convert to a String at the last moment before it is displayed. All your internal calculations should be using Date or ideally JodaTime's LocalDate

Comment: @Azodious ya i searched in SO, i also went through the link that u posted, but, i didn't understand what unix timestamp is...

Comment: @PeterLawrey i will give it a try...and yes i'am from NEPAL...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get time in milliseconds by calling `getTime()`. Then compare `long` values. 
`milliis/1000` gives seconds, `millis/60/1000` gives minutes, `millis/3600/1000` gives hours, etc.

You can also use 3rd party libraries like JodaTime but if you need this one-time Joda is too much.

Comment: Could u please show some examples