# Convert ms (long) to mm:ss

Tags: java, jsp, time, long-integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Milliseconds to “X mins, x seconds” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java)

Hello I need convert in JSP file long value that show number of milliseconds to format mm:ss

```
<td>${values.parameters.timeLong}</td>
```

Comment: do it server side and print it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (with a format of `"mm.ss"`). I would perhaps do this on the server and provide the JSP with a pre-rendered value.

Beware that this class isn't thread-safe and a better alternative is available via [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Too bad.. its too easy..

```
 x = input/ 1000;
    minutes = x % 60;
    seconds = x - ( minutes * 60 )
```

This will be faster than using SimpleDateFormat

Comment: you should divide by 1000 first for minutes.

Comment: You still need to print/format this. It's precisely for these reasons that I advocate using libs wherever possible.

Comment: Yes I agree with Brian; if you are particular that output should be 08:07 ; then its better to use SimpleDateFormat.