# How to check how many time is the phone ON?

Tags: android

It is possible to check how many time is the phone on since the last time was powered on ?

for example, i powered off the phone last night, and 12 hours ago i powered on the phone, so... i need to know how to get these 12 hours powered on value from the phone.

It is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elapsedRealTime()
```

will give you the time since the device was last booted

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()

Comment: to convert the elapsed time in milliseconds to more human readable figures see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java (that call gives you how long since the phone was started not the time at which it was started)