# Converting Milliseconds to Minutes and Seconds?

Tags: java, time, type-conversion, stopwatch, watch

I have looked through previous questions, but none had the answer I was looking for.
How do I convert milliseconds from a StopWatch method to Minutes and Seconds?
I have:

```
 watch.start();
```

to start the stopwatch and

```
  watch.stop();
```

to stop the watch. I later have

```
  watch.getTime();
```

which returns Milliseconds. I want it to return in Seconds and Minutes. How do I go about doing so? I'm looking for a way to do it without multiplying/dividing by 1000 but rather a method that will make the whole computation more readable and less error-prone.

Comment: x milliseconds = x / 1000 seconds. Then z seconds = z / 60 minutes. You could do z % 60 to find the number of seconds remaining.

Comment: basic math: 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds. 60 seconds = 1 minute.

Comment: Check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java. Should get you what you want.

Comment: This is actually a really simple question. What have you tried?

Comment: You can do like this https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/converting-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds/

Answer (score 234):

I would suggest using `TimeUnit`. You can use it like this:

```
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);
```

Comment: My only issue is I don't know: How to define millis (It is returning as "millis cannot be resolved to a variable" and I don't know how to access it in a System.out.println(); method.

Comment: You can do this using just numbers if milliseconds is already something like a long. There is little need to introduce a new library just to do a simple calculation. `minutes = ((milliseconds / 1000) / 60)`

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for Java 5 through 7.

Comment: @Sotti Brilliant? This does not address the Question! The Question asks for minutes ***and*** seconds, as the readout of a stopwatch, for example `1 minute 30 seconds` This Answer provides minutes ***or*** seconds, for example `1 minute 90 seconds`.

Comment: I would like to use it but with seconds as a double, not ints, for example 1.5s. Is this somethow possible?

Answer (score 65):

After converting millis to seconds (by dividing by 1000), you can use `/ 60` to get the minutes value, and `% 60` (remainder) to get the "seconds in minute" value.

```
long millis = .....;  // obtained from StopWatch
long minutes = (millis / 1000)  / 60;
int seconds = (int)((millis / 1000) % 60);
```

Comment: You can do like this https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/converting-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds/

Comment: last line was a life saver for the Timer control, using the designer properties instead, thanks!

Answer (score 39):

## tl;dr

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis( … ) ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart() ;
```

## Java 9 and later

In Java 9 and later, create a `Duration` and call the `to…Part` methods. In this case: `toMinutesPart` and `toSecondsPart`.

Capture the start & stop of your stopwatch.

```
Instant start = Instant.now(); 
…
Instant stop = Instant.now();
```

Represent elapsed time in a `Duration` object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Interrogate for each part, the minutes and the seconds.

```
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart();
int seconds = d.toSecondsPart();
```

You might also want to see if your stopwatch ran expectedly long.

```
Boolean ranTooLong = ( d.toDaysPart() > 0 ) || ( d.toHoursPart() > 0 ) ;
```

## Java 8

In Java 8, the `Duration` class lacks `to…Part` methods. You will need to do math as shown in the other Answers.

```
long entireDurationAsSeconds = d.getSeconds();
```

Or let `Duration` do the math.

```
long minutesPart = d.toMinutes(); 
long secondsPart = d.minusMinutes( minutesPart ).getSeconds() ;
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/eGnTdC).

> Interval: 2016-12-18T08:39:34.099Z/2016-12-18T08:41:49.099Z
>
> d.toString(): PT2M15S
>
> d.getSeconds(): 135
>
> Elapsed: 2M 15S

### Resolution

FYI, the resolution of `now` methods changed between Java 8 and Java 9. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20689055/642706).

- **Java 9** captures the moment with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds. Resolution depends on capability of your computer’s hardware. I see microseconds (six digits of decimal fraction) on MacBook Pro Retina with macOS Sierra.
- **Java 8** captures the moment only up to milliseconds. The implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) is limited to a resolution of milliseconds. So you can *store* values in nanoseconds but only *capture* them in milliseconds.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: for android call require api level 26.

Comment: @Killer For earlier Android, see the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) projects.

Answer (score 16):

I was creating a mp3 player app for android, so I did it like this to get current time and duration

```
 private String millisecondsToTime(long milliseconds) {
    long minutes = (milliseconds / 1000) / 60;
    long seconds = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
    String secondsStr = Long.toString(seconds);
    String secs;
    if (secondsStr.length() >= 2) {
        secs = secondsStr.substring(0, 2);
    } else {
        secs = "0" + secondsStr;
    }

    return minutes + ":" + secs;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is just basic math.
1000 milliseconds=1 second and 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute;
So just do,

```
int seconds=(millis/1000)%60;

long minutes=((millis-seconds)/1000)/60;
```

Comment: There's a mistake - the second line should be `(millis/1000-seconds)/60`

Answer (score 11):

```
  public static String getIntervalTime(long longInterval) {
    
    long intMillis = longInterval;
    long dd = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(intMillis);
    long daysMillis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(dd);
    intMillis -= daysMillis;
    long hh = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(intMillis);
    long hoursMillis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hh);
    intMillis -= hoursMillis;
    long mm = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(intMillis);
    long minutesMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(mm);
    intMillis -= minutesMillis;
    long ss = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(intMillis);
    long secondsMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(ss);
    intMillis -= secondsMillis;

    String stringInterval = "%02d days - %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d";
    return String.format(stringInterval , dd, hh, mm, ss, intMillis);
  }
```

Shorter Form!

```
  public static String getIntervalTime(long longInterval) {

    long intMillis = longInterval;
    long dd = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(intMillis);
    intMillis -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(dd);
    long hh = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(intMillis);
    intMillis -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hh);
    long mm = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(intMillis);
    intMillis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(mm);
    long ss = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(intMillis);
    intMillis -= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(ss);

    String stringInterval = "%02d days - %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d";
    return String.format(stringInterval , dd, hh, mm, ss, intMillis);
  }
```

Testing

```
long delay = 1000*60*20 + 1000*5 + 10;
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Delay Expected {0}", getIntervalTime(delay));
```

Output

```
INFO: Delay Expected 00 days - 00:20:05.010
```

Answer (score 8):

To convert time in millis directly to minutes: second format you can use this

```
String durationText = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(timeInMillis / 1000));
```

This will return a string with time in proper formatting. 
It worked for me.

Comment: Ahah, good one! I just tested on a timer which was in milliseconds and worked!

Comment: Nice approach! Given the formula going around, seems to be Miliseconds / 1000 % 60. Given the timer, will be timer1.Interval in place of Miliseconds etc.

Answer (score 7):

I need to convert millisecond to minute and second for timer so I used this code.

```
private String getTime(long millisecond) {
    
    long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisecond);
    long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisecond) - 
       TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisecond));

    String time = min + ":" + sec;
    return time;
}
```

for revers, each minute equals 60,000 millisecond and each second equals 1000 millisecond. So :

```
 long millisecond = minutes * 60000;
 long millisecond = seconds * 1000;
```

or

```
 long millisecond = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds);
```

Answer (score 6):

X milliseconds = X / 1000 seconds = (X / 1000) / 60 minutes

If you have 100,000 milliseconds, divide this value by 1,000 and you're left with 100 seconds. Now 100 / 60 = 1.666~ minutes, but fractional minutes have no value, so: do 100 % 60 = 40 seconds to find the remainder, then integer division 100 / 60 = 1 minute, with 40 seconds remainder. Answer: 1 minute, 40 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the full program

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Milliseconds {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long milliseconds = 1000000;

    // long minutes = (milliseconds / 1000) / 60;
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds);

    // long seconds = (milliseconds / 1000);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliseconds);

    System.out.format("%d Milliseconds = %d minutes\n", milliseconds, minutes );
    System.out.println("Or");
    System.out.format("%d Milliseconds = %d seconds", milliseconds, seconds );

}
}
```

I found this program here "[Link](https://coderforevers.com/java/java-program/milliseconds-minutes-seconds/)" there it is explained in detail.

Comment: This does **not address the Question**. The Question asks for minutes *and* seconds, as a readout of a stopwatch. You give two separate results, minutes *or* seconds.d

Answer (score 5):

To get actual hour, minute and seconds as appear on watch try this code

```
val sec = (milliSec/1000) % 60
val min = ((milliSec/1000) / 60) % 60
val hour = ((milliSec/1000) / 60) / 60
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try proceeding this way:

Pass ms value from

```
Long ms = watch.getTime();
```

to

```
getDisplayValue(ms)
```

Kotlin implementation:

```
fun getDisplayValue(ms: Long): String {
        val duration = Duration.ofMillis(ms)
        val minutes = duration.toMinutes()
        val seconds = duration.minusMinutes(minutes).seconds

        return "${minutes}min ${seconds}sec"
}
```

Java implementation:

```
public String getDisplayValue(Long ms) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(ms);
        Long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
        Long seconds = duration.minusMinutes(minutes).getSeconds();

        return minutes + "min " + seconds "sec"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Java 1.5 support concurrent TimeUnit.  Otherwise, I would suggest for TimeUnit.  Below is based on pure math approach.

```
stopWatch.stop();
long milliseconds = stopWatch.getTime();

int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds / 1000) % 60);
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / 1000) / 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert miliseconds into seconds, minutes and hours.

```
                val millis = **milliSecondsYouWantToConvert**
                val seconds = (millis / 1000) % 60
                val minutes = ((millis / 1000) / 60) % 60
                val hours = ((millis / 1000) / 60) / 60

                println("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
                println(String.format("%02dh : %02dm : %02ds remaining", hours, minutes, seconds))
                println("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
**RESULT :** 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  01h : 23m : 37s remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code does the work for converting ms to min:secs with [m:ss] format

```
int seconds;
int minutes;
String Sec;
long Mills = ...;  // Milliseconds goes here
minutes = (int)(Mills / 1000)  / 60;
seconds = (int)((Mills / 1000) % 60);
Sec = seconds+"";

TextView.setText(minutes+":"+Sec);//Display duration [3:40]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert milliseconds to **hours, minutes and seconds** using this method

```
public String timeConversion(Long millie) {
    if (millie != null) {
        long seconds = (millie / 1000);
        long sec = seconds % 60;
        long min = (seconds / 60) % 60;
        long hrs = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
        if (hrs > 0) {
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hrs, min, sec);
        } else {
            return String.format("%02d:%02d", min, sec);
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then use this method like this

```
videoDuration.setText(timeConversion((long) milliSecondsHere));
```

In Kotlin

```
fun timeConverter(millie: Long): String {
return run {
    val seconds: Long = millie / 2000
    val sec = seconds % 60
    val min = seconds / 60 % 60
    val hrs = seconds / (60 * 60) % 24
    return if (hrs > 0) {
        String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hrs, min, sec)
    } else {
        String.format("%02d:%02d", min, sec)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.v3mobi.userpersistdatetime;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        startDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); //set your start time
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        endDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // set  your end time

        chekUserPersistence();

    }

    private void chekUserPersistence()
    {
        long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
//        long duration = 301000;

        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);         // minutes ok
        long secs = (duration/1000) % 60;         // minutes ok


        Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Diff  "
                +  diffInMinutes + " : "+ secs , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        System.out.println("Diff  " + diffInMinutes +" : "+ secs );

        Log.e("keshav","diffInMinutes -->" +diffInMinutes);
        Log.e("keshav","secs -->" +secs);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Lang class [`DurationFormatUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html). This class has some standard formats out of the box but also supports custom formats.

```
String result = DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(millis, "mm:ss.SSS' sec.'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get seconds and minutes from the miliseconds

```
    fun main() {
    val mili = 150000
    val min = mili/1000/60
    val sec: Double = (mili.toDouble()/60000.0 - 2.0) * 60
    println(mili)
    println(min)
    println(sec)
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple solution. 
Example calls that could be used in any method:

- `StopWatch.start();`
- `StopWatch.stop();`
- `StopWatch.displayDiff();` displays difference in minutes and seconds   between start and stop. (elapsed time)

  ```
  import java.time.Duration;
  import java.time.Instant;


  public class StopWatch {

      private static Instant start;
      private static Instant stop;

      private void StopWatch() {
          // not called
      }

      public static void start() {
          start = Instant.now();
      }

      public static void stop() {
          stop = Instant.now();
      }

      public static void displayDiff() {
          Duration totalTime = Duration.between(start, stop);
          System.out.println(totalTime.toMinutes() + " Minutes " 
                             + totalTime.toMillis() / 1000 + " Seconds");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Incorrect. The `toMillis` method reports the *entire* duration as milliseconds.

Answer (score -2):

This is related to a previous post, but in my opinion the solution proposed wasn't quite right. 
In order to realize a correct conversion, this is what should be implemnted:

```
long time_millis = 1926546
int minutes = time_millis / 1000 / 60
int seconds = ((int)(time_millis / 1000) % 60) #important that this division is cast to an int

println "Build time: $minutes minutes $seconds seconds"
```

Comment: I am glad you want to help with providing a solution to a problem. However, needs to be improved. Possible, you should format the code properly, plus you can link to the question you want to correct. Moreove, are you sure that this is Java? Please tag the language you are using.