# Equivalent of Erlang now() in Java

Tags: java, datetime, erlang

I am working on a project which requires timestamps for running threads. In Erlang, when we do now() we get something like

`{1529,709564,578215}` which represent `{megaseconds, seconds, microseconds}`

since epoch. So, for two processes spawned at the same time, I can get same microseconds value. Is there a way to replicate this function in Java?

I know about `Date.getTime()` which gives us the milliseconds since epoch time, but it does not serve the purpose since I cannot get a unique microsecond value from it after dividing by order of magnitude.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        System.out.println(Instant.now());
```

Output just now was:

> 2018-06-23T05:16:45.768006Z

On the Java 10 on my Mac it gave microsecond precision. Since Java 9 it will on many operating systems, maybe not all. `Instant.now()` returns an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). An `Instant` is implemented as seconds and nanoseconds since the epoch, and you can get out those individually if you want.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But I am unsure whether Instant.now() outputs in microsecond precision (which Erlang now() does). I was referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689231/4244347 answer while making the above claim. Any explanation/correction is welcome.

Comment: Java relies on the OS and the hardware for the precision. So does Erlang necessarily. So I would expect it to be the same. I obviously have not tested on all OSs and hardware configurations.