# .toNanos() method does not work correctly

Tags: java, java-8, duration, nanotime

I tried to make a method that will give me an idea of how much time it takes to my programs to run, and for an unknown reason, I can not get the nanoseconds.

I tried to read about the below classes but could not find out what I am doing wrong:
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

The methods:

```
public static String calcExecutionTime(Instant startTime, Instant endTime) {
    if ((Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toNanos()) < 1000000) {
        return Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toNanos() + " nanoseconds.";
    } else if ((Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMillis()) < 1000) {
        return Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMillis() + " milliseconds.";
    } else if ((Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toSeconds()) < 100) {
        return Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toSeconds() + " seconds.";
    } else if ((Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMinutes()) < 60) {
        return Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMinutes() + " minutes.";
    } else {
        return Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toHours() + " hoursm.";
    }
}
```

Main here:

```
    Instant instantStart = Instant.now();
    Instant instantEnd = Instant.now();
    System.out.print("Execution time for this program: " + calcExecutionTime(instantStart, instantEnd));
```

If I use the old System.nanoTime(); I get a result of 300-400 nanoseconds but with toNanos() I get 0 in this same situation.

Edit:
I do not use getNano() I use toNanos()

Comment: `Duration#toNanos()` works fine, it is `Instant.now()` which gives you twice same time causing duration to be 0.

Comment: Hint: print out the `Instant` instances and `Duration.between(startTime, endTime)`

Comment: Maybe your system does not provide this information. As mentioned already log both values and additional see this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689055/java-8-instant-now-with-nanosecond-resolution#20689231

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Instant.now() with nanosecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689055/java-8-instant-now-with-nanosecond-resolution)

Comment: In class `Clock` shows, `Instant.now()` is inited by milliseconds. ```public Instant instant() {
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis());
 }```

Comment: @caisil That has been improved since Java 9, but still doesn’t give nanosecond precision (on any platform that I know of).

Comment: @perdian this is not duplicate because I do not use getNano I use toNanos and it is different question

Comment: Couldn't you just store `Duration.between(startTime, endTime)` into a variable?

Comment: do you really need nano-seconds? I suggest: [Avoiding Benchmarking Pitfalls on the JVM](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html), [Common benchmarking pitfalls](https://plumbr.io/blog/performance-blog/common-benchmarking-pitfalls), [Why Are Java Microbenchmarks Hard?](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html#why-are-java-microbenchmarks-hard) and others

Comment: I still believe it is a duplicate of *Java 8 Instant.now() with nanosecond resolution?* The call to `getNano()` in that question was just to make it still clearer that the `Instant` has zeroes in the last 6 positions of the nanos, that is, effectively only millisecond precision. (I may consider closing as duplicate, but will at least await your counter-arguments before doing so.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @Pshemo's comment about `Instant.now()`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-- :

> This will query the [system UTC clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#systemUTC--) to obtain the current instant.

Where the link leads to:

> This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), or a higher resolution clock if one is available.

So it may or may not have a higher precision than milliseconds. In your case the "may not have" seems to apply.

Comment: Is there a better approach to do what I am trying to do (how much time it takes to my programs to run)?

Comment: @UIUX: you can check the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689055/java-8-instant-now-with-nanosecond-resolution link from the comments. It provides a nano-resolution `Clock`, which can be used with `now()` (there is a `now(Clock)` variant, immediately below the one I linked).