# Mocking System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

One can use Clock to mock calls like `System.currentTimeMillis()` using `Clock.millis()` and injecting a mock implementation of Clock.

Is there a similar way to easily mock `System.nanoTime()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689055/java-8-instant-now-with-nanosecond-resolution#:~:text=While%20default%20Java8%20clock%20does%20not%20provide%20nanoseconds%20resolution%2C%20you%20can%20combine%20it%20with%20Java%20ability%20to%20measure%20time%20differences%20with%20nanoseconds%20resolution%2C%20thus%20creating%20an%20actual%20nanosecond%2Dcapable%20clock.

Answer (score 2):

## Use your own encapsulation

```
interface NanoTimer {
  long nanoTime();
  static NanoTimer system() {
    return System::nanoTime;
  }
}
```

This way you can write your own mock very easily.

Alternatively, I can't see any use case besides a stopwatch, so I guess that you'd probably want to have a look at Guava's [`Stopwatch`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Guava's [`Ticker`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Ticker.html) class that does exactly that.

Or, if you're simply trying to measure time properly, you can use [`Stopwatch`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) for extra functionality and nicer API, its constructor takes a Ticker instance.

There's even a `FakeTicker` in [`guava-testlib`](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava-testlib) if you find any of the other utilities in there useful. Otherwise writing a fake Ticker is obviously very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a interface for dependency injection during unit tests:

```
public class YourClass {
    private static TimeSupplier timeSupplier = System::nanoTime;

    @VisibleForTesting
    public static void setTimeSupplier(TimeSupplier timeSupplier) {
        YourClass.timeSupplier = timeSupplier;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface TimeSupplier {
        long nanoTime();
    }
    
    // Just use timeSupplier.nanoTime() instead of the static nanoTime calls
}
```

Then you can simply stub the timeout with a constant (Mockito for example):

```
YourClass.TimeSupplier timeSupplier = mock(YourClass.TimeSupplier.class);
when(timeSupplier.nanoTime()).thenReturn(20221116L);
YourClass.setTimeSupplier(timeSupplier);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [`Clock.instant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#instant()). According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html):

> the class stores a long representing epoch-seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second

You can access the nano-part using [`Instant.getNano()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#getNano()).

It's not equivalent, but it's analogous and it provides you with the same functionality. You even do not need to read the nano value, `Instant` **represents** the nano time. And you have arithmetical functions defined on the `Instant` class, such as `minus(Instant)`, `minusNanos(long)` etc.

Comment: `Instant::getNano` gives only the nano part of the `Instant` instance, while `System::nanoTime` returns "the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds". That's not even roughly equivalent.

Comment: @tquadrat Of course it's not *equivalent*, it's **analogous**. You even do not need the nano value, `Instant` represents a nano time. And you have arithmetical functions defined on the `Instant` class, such as `minus(Instant)`, `minusNanos(long)` etc.

Comment: `System.nanoTime` uses monotonic clock, it can't go backwards, it won't slow down / speed up because of NTP. I do not know how to get that with Clock/Instant.

Comment: @PetrJaneček Of course it depends on your use case. If you are developing a real-time application and you are *critically* dependent on these properties, then you are right. Otherwise it's just academic. For **microbenchmarks**, you can never perform one measure only, you must run it many times and calculate the average, so rare fluctuations will not matter.

Comment: @HonzaZidek – It's not even analogous. But for a mock, equivalency is needed …