# Spring @Scheduled cron job in combination with Instant.now()

Tags: java, spring, cron, java.time.instant

In Spring I use standard CRON job scheduling to do some business level measurements every 10 minutes with this example

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 * * * ?")
public void takeMeasurements() {
    Instant dateTimeNow = Instant.now();

    // Business impl of measurements taking & storing into DB
}
```

I've had no problem with this impl in under multiple customer environments (Win, MacOS, Linux) running as SpringBoot containers in docker but I observed that in one Win10 Enterprise environment the timestamp coming from `Instant.now()` called when CRON job fires has time "in past" e.g. `11:59:59:998` with job that was supposed to be fired at 12:00:00.

I can handle this scenario with some accepted range of deviation (for my purposes it's OK to do "rounding" of +-30s) but for some folks/scenarios it might not be.

Where is the underlying problem of this?

Doesn't CRON use same machine clock as `java.time.Instant` uses?

Comment: Have you tried to run a code on Java 9+? It is also a good solution was described by @StormeHawke - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689298/12312179

Comment: Forgot to mention - all my containers run with JDK 11