# BeanMatchers Could not generate two distinct values after 128 attempts of type java.time.Instant

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

When I am trying to run the following test:

```
    @Test
    public void testHash() {
        BeanMatchers.registerValueGenerator(Instant::now, Instant.class);
        assertThat(ClassForTest.class, hasValidBeanHashCode());
    }
```

for the class:

```
class ClassForTest {
    private Instant instant;

    public Instant getInstant() {
        return instant;
    }

    public void setInstant(Instant instant) {
        this.instant = instant;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ClassForTest that = (ClassForTest) o;
        return Objects.equals(instant, that.instant);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(instant);
    }
}
```

where `BeanMatchers` class comes from:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.bean-matchers</groupId>
            <artifactId>bean-matchers</artifactId>
            <version>0.14</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am constantly getting the following exception:

> BeanMatchers Could not generate two distinct values after 128 attempts of type java.time.Instant

Any ideas why I see this exception and how to fix it? Because, technically, the test is implemented in the right way.

Comment: Have you tried registering a pseudo-random value generator for `Instant`? Maybe two instances created by `Instant.now()` are not "sufficiently different" for the bean matchers lib. But that's mere speculation.

Comment: Or maybe you're hit by https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689231/32352 and all Instants created in short intervals have the actual same value. You may want to slow your generator function artificially down to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, I resolved it like this

```
@Test
public void testHash() {
    BeanMatchers.registerValueGenerator(this::registerInstant, Instant.class);

    assertThat(ClassForTest.class, hasValidBeanHashCode());
}

private Instant registerInstant() {
    List<Instant> times = Arrays.asList(Instant.now(), Instant.now().minusSeconds(10));

    return times.get(new Random().nextInt(times.size()));
}
```