# How to get the current minute for playing YouTube video in Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have the YouTube player embedded in my Android application. I want to get the current minute of the video playing once I press the device's back button. I tried doing this:

```
  @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Ini ");

    if(!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
        int minute  = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();

    }

    Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Fi ");

}
```

but without success; the minute is always 0. I don't know why.

Any help?

Comment: Did you play the player first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the video is playing, you can get the current millis using this

```
long millis = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
```

and just convert it to minutes & seconds. The best i've found so far for conversion is using this code

```
long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/17625247/5870896

Comment: in which method of the activity should i put this: long millis = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();

Comment: anywhere you want as long as there is a playing video

Comment: @SecretCoder i cant use this method inside onDestroy .  any workout to get current time at the time of exit the screen?