# Call Restful api periodically from a java program

Tags: java, http

Hi I'm developing a java application wherein I need to call Restful api again and again after a specific time interval (say 10 seconds) and this would continue for a few days. (I'm using `Apache HttpClient` library to call the service.)

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(rest-URL);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
```

Which is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Use scheduler or call the rest url using unix/shell scripts

Comment: Add the request to a [Scheduled Executor Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 1):

Schedulers or Timers could be used to make the call every so often. You could also put that code inside a while loop and check System.currentTimeMillis(), run a modulus operation on it to return the time and drop into your code

Working from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java).

```
while(true){
    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
    int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
    int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

    if( /* time is right */ ){
         //  REST calls here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a form of pooling. Won't this consume a lot of unnecessary CPU time? A java scheduler like Quartz or cron4j can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). For the restful api, I think [Jersey framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) is much easier to use than Apache HttpClient.