# Android: ListAdapter - multiple objects to one TextView? and Convert millis to mins

Tags: android

how can I put multiple objects from List into one textview in ListAdapter?
Here is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_browser);
musichelper msc = new musichelper(this);
List<HashMap<String, String>> musics = msc.buildMusic();
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

ListAdapter la = new SimpleAdapter(this, musics, R.layout.song_list,
        new String[] { "artist"+" - "+"title", "duration" }, new int[] { R.id.pickerName, R.id.pickerLength }
        );
lv.setAdapter(la);
```

This ends up having no artist and no title but I want it to be like: Artist - Song Name assigned to TextView called R.id.pickerName.

Also duration is in milliseconds, how can I convert it directly when building ListAdapter? I want milliseconds for example: 414616 to be written as: 7:31 (I think)

[image]

This is what I end up with when trying to combine Artist + - + Title.
And as you see - duration appears in milliseconds.

I know I could do all of the above when building the List of objects but I would like to keep them as seperate objects.

Answer (score 0):

The String array is a mapping of the key in the HashMap to the list.

In `msc.buildMusic()`, when you are adding the duration to the `HashMap` you need to change the [milliseconds to the format you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java). Then you add the String with the format into the hashmap instead of the milliseconds. Also, you will need to add a new line that puts the artist and the title into the HashMap with the key `artist - title`. (I recommend you remove the spacing)