# Android: Substract two Datetime from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I Have data in database in SQLite like this.

```
ID   COLUMN_SBEGIN         COLUMN_SEND
1    2015-10-08 22:00:00   2015-10-09 08:00:00
```

I want to get how many HOURS from `22:00:00` to `08:00:00`. Do you have any idea?

Here my code!

```
public void sleepProcess() throws ParseException {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ProviderSleep.CONTENT_URI, Helper.ALL_SLEEP,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.COLUMN_SBEGIN)); //get the time data
    String temp2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.COLUMN_SEND)); //get the time data

    java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date t1 = df.parse(temp);
    java.util.Date t2 = df.parse(temp2);
    long sumSleep = t2.getTime() - t1.getTime();

    //sumSleep should in Hours(Integer)

    if(sumSleep < 8){
        sleep.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);
    }else{
        sleep.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know. Thank's for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the difference in milliseconds:

```
long sumSleep = t2.getTime() - t1.getTime();
```

So to according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625624/3850595) to convert it in hours up to `Java 5`:

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(sumSleep))
```

Or, with `Java 4` or less

```
int hours   = (int) ((sumSleep / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `sumSleep` contains difference between `t1` and `t2` in milliseconds. So you just need to convert it to hours.

```
long millisInHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
long elapsedHours = sumSleep / millisInHour;
```