# Transforming long milliseconds into 00:00:00.000 format string

Tags: java

Converting a long millisecond value in to the format 00:00:00.000. I can't have hours wrapping around. So I cant' use `DateFormat`.

```
long millis = 3600000;
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));
//Output: 01:00:00
```

This code excludes milliseconds.

Comment: Why so complicated? Just use Javas Dateformat-API. Simple, fast and no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/625624/2958086

Comment: @Paul It doesn't help me, If I use dateformat it I choose to display it in a 24hours format (HH) and the the time is past noon, the milliseconds equivalent to 1hour will display as 13. If I put it as a 12hours format (hh), and the milliseconds are enough for 14hours or so, it will show as 2hours.

Compass Either of those codes will return it the way I need, most they do is exactly what I already did on the code I posted.

Comment: @MarcelCaferati I don't quite get what your problem is. `HH:mm:ss.SSS` as format-string works just fine for me. Matches your format, correct time, everything's just the way it's supposed to be... . As for the thing with the hours: I don't exactly get where the problem would be with a 24hr-format behaving the way it's supposed to be (and same for 12hr-format)? If it's just the issue with 24:01 and comparable formats, just use `k` instead of `H` for the hours (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) )

Comment: @Paul I also tried that already, the problem is that dateformat corrects the time based on real world hours based on the day. But my problem is that the milliseconds I am using have absolutely no relation to the day, it is simply a lap time. Example: "the racer took 1 hour (3600000) milliseconds for that lap" I will be adding to that time the penalty "1hour penalty" so his time will be a total of 2hours. I am not saying there is a problem with the api. I am just assuming it doesn't work for that purpose. BUT I will give it another try. Thank you

Comment: @MarcelCaferati So you want the hours to not wrap around? Well, that'd have been quite useful info in the question in the first place. In that case: where's the problem with proceeding with your approach and simply including the milliseconds as well using the same pattern?

Comment: @Paul I tried using the same code yea, but I can't understand how it works, I can't simply add another "%03d" and put another parameter on that "string.format" in order to get the milliseconds remaining from the last "%" . It won't accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
long millis = 3600000;
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d",  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1),
    millis % 1000);
```

It extends the format-string by `".%03d"` and adds the milliseconds (`millis % 1000`) to the parameter-list. Tested on java v1.8.0_91 (Oracle JRE).