# Convert IntegerProperty into hh:mm:ss String binding and bind to Label

Tags: java, javafx

I belive question in title is detailed enough.

Are there tools that allow to do this easily in javafx?

As per comment:
IntegerProperty is abstraction in JavaFX. Here I am using SimpleIntegerProperty.

I'd like to convert integer binding to said time format (as binding).

Main problem here is how can I do it with relatively short code (I expect fx provides some tricks for this - like for everything else).

Comment: The question is not detailed enough.  No idea what the IntegerProperty is intended to represent.

Comment: Also it's never a good idea to include a integral part of the question only in the title...

Comment: @Ernio What does your `IntegerProperty`represent? seconds? milliseconds? can you give an example of what you want the property to translate as?

Comment: Question is clear enough. OP is asking how to format an SimpleIntegerProperty binding to a Label. If the SimpleIntegerProperty contained the value "2", then a binding to the label such as `hoursLabel.textProperty().bind(hoursSimpleIntProp.asString());` would have the label display "2". But OP wants "02" for the hoursLabel.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your `IntegerProperty` represents a number of seconds? If so, siddhadev's answer on [How to convert Milliseconds to “X mins, x seconds” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625433/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-x-mins-x-seconds-in-java) gives a great way to format an integer representing a time unit into a `String`. All that is left to do is to add a listener to your property and set the formatted `String` from there.

```
public static String formatStringToTime(int seconds){
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(time),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(time) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes((TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(time))),
            time - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(time)));
}

...

//main method
IntegerProperty prop = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
prop.addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> yourObject.setString(formatStringToTime(nv));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `SimpleIntegerProperty` is set to a *single-digit* value such as 9. To bind this value to your `Label` with a 0 prefixed, simply say:

```
label.textProperty().bind(simpleIntegerProperty.asString("%02d"));
```

This will achieve your desired format: `hh:mm:ss`