# How to subtract two times of different dates in java

Tags: java

How do i subtract two times which are in two different dates, say 23:20:45 of 2019/07/24 and 00:10:32 of 2019/07/25.
It should return me the difference between those two hours:minutes:seconds.

I have to note the duration of people which log into the system at night, but as the date changes it's a bit difficult to do so I need some code in java which will return me the exact time in hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: *regardless of the date*!!! So 20:00:00 of 2019/07/24 and 20:00:00 of 2019/07/25 will return 0? I don't think so. Rephrase your question.

Comment: Rephrased the question.

Comment: you can use milli/nano seconds

Comment: In the linked original question I in particular recommend [the answer by Vitalii Fedorenko using java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176621/5772882).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.parse("2019/07/24 23:20:45", formatter);
LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.parse("2019/07/25 00:10:32", formatter);
System.out.println(Duration.between(to.toLocalTime(),from.toLocalTime()).getSeconds());
```

So, since the requrements recently changed and it is now about the total duration between to moments in time, and not the duration between the time-part only, omitting the date-part, the whole thing gets simpler, then it it's just

`System.out.println(Duration.between(to,from).getSeconds());`

... and a duplicate question ...

Comment: How does subtracting time without date make any sense? I’m confused.

Comment: Got it. You might want to note that that in your Answer, as it seems the Question has been edited, changing the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Your logs should be recording the users’ activity using a moment in UTC, written as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, and is pronounced “Zulu”. Example: `2019-07-24T23:20:45Z`.

The `Instant` class represented a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
String output = instant.now();
```

Parse.

```
Instant start = Instant.parse( "2019-07-24T23:20:45Z" ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Report the duration in standard ISO 8601 text, [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```