# How can I "pretty print" a Duration in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, date, time

Does anyone know of a Java library that can pretty print a number in milliseconds in the same way that C# does?

E.g., 123456 ms as a long would be printed as 4d1h3m5s.

Comment: FYI, the format you seem to be describing is a [`Duration`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) defined in the sensible standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` means "Period" and marks the beginning, `T` separates the date portion from time portion, and in between are optional occurrances of a number with a single-letter abbreviation. For example, `PT4H30M` = four and a half hours.

Comment: If all else fails it's a very simple matter to do it yourself.  Just use successive applications of `%` and `/` to split the number into parts.  Almost easier than some of the proposed answers.

Comment: @HotLicks Leave it to library methods for much cleaner and clearer code than using `/` and `%`.

Comment: Yes, in the intervening 8 years since I asked this question (!) I've moved over to joda time which suits my use case very well

Comment: @phatmanace The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, and advises migration to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) has a pretty good way to do this using a [PeriodFormatterBuilder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html).

Quick Win: `PeriodFormat.getDefault().print(duration.toPeriod());`

e.g.

```
//import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
//import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;
//import org.joda.time.Duration;

Duration duration = new Duration(123456); // in milliseconds
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .appendDays()
     .appendSuffix("d")
     .appendHours()
     .appendSuffix("h")
     .appendMinutes()
     .appendSuffix("m")
     .appendSeconds()
     .appendSuffix("s")
     .toFormatter();
String formatted = formatter.print(duration.toPeriod());
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: It appears from an answer below that an instance of Period can be created directly, without first creating a Duration instance and then converting it to Period. E.g. Period period = new Period(millis); String formatted = formatter.print(period);

Comment: Beware of this "duration.toPeriod()" conversion. If the duration is quite big, the day portion onwards would remain as 0. The hours portion will keep growing. You will get 25h10m23s but never get the "d". The reason is there is no fully correct way to convert hours to days in Joda's strict ways. Most of the cases, if you are comparing two instants and wanting to print it, you can do new Period(t1, t2) instead of new Duration(t1, t2).toPeriod().

Comment: @Boon do you know how to convert duration to period with respect to days? I use duration from which I can substitute second in my on my timer. Event setting `PeriodType.daysTime()` or `.standard()` didn't help

Comment: @murt If you really want to, and can accept the standard definition of a day, then you can "formatter.print(duration.toPeriod().normalizedStandard())" in the code above. Have fun!

Answer (score 141):

I've built a simple solution, using Java 8's `Duration.toString()` and a bit of regex:

```
public static String humanReadableFormat(Duration duration) {
    return duration.toString()
            .substring(2)
            .replaceAll("(\\d[HMS])(?!$)", "$1 ")
            .toLowerCase();
}
```

The result will look like:

```
- 5h
- 7h 15m
- 6h 50m 15s
- 2h 5s
- 0.1s
```

If you don't want spaces between, just remove `replaceAll`.

Comment: You should never rely on the output of toStrong() because this may change in further versions.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf it's not likely to change, since it's specified in the javadoc

Comment: @Weltraumschaf Unlikely to change as the output of [`Duration::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) is formatted according to the well-defined and well-worn [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Comment: If you don't want fractions, add `.replaceAll("\\.\\d+", "")` before the call to `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf Generally when something may change in future versions they explicitly mention it in the Javadoc or don't document it at all. Since they don't do that, we shouldn't assume it is subject to change otherwise where do we draw the line? Many things are documented and sure, there's always the miniscule chance they change their mind, but since they do mention when things shouldn't be relied on then it's safe to assume it won't change.

Comment: That's simply not true. I had the experience with a legacy system: From one Java version to the next (I guess it was 1.5 to 1.6) the number of fraction digits from `Float#toString()` changed from 4 to 3 digits. This prevented the company I worked for years to upgrade Java. Of course you can use toString(), but for other things than debugging or logging it is a bad architectural choice and should be avoided IMHO.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf Your point in generally correct and I wouldn't myself rely on the toString() output of most classes. But in this very specific case, the method **definition** states that its output follows the ISO-8601 standard, as you can see in the method's [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toString()). So it's not an implementation detail like in most classes, therefore not something I would expect a language as mature as Java to change like that,

Comment: How would you add days in the above solution?

Comment: @Weltraumschaf by that logic, you should never rely on the output of _any_ third-party method.

Comment: @lucasls yes, ok. In this particular case. Since exceptions are not that good, I would prefer another method named accordingly.

Answer (score 29):

Apache commons-lang provides the [DurationFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DurationFormatUtils.html) class to get this done as well. It has several formatting methods like `formatDurationHMS` and `formatDurationISO`, but if you just want a nice output, use:

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(123456, true, true);
```

Result

```
2 minutes 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 20):

Java 9+

```
Duration d1 = Duration.ofDays(0);
        d1 = d1.plusHours(47);
        d1 = d1.plusMinutes(124);
        d1 = d1.plusSeconds(124);
System.out.println(String.format("%s d %sh %sm %ss", 
                d1.toDaysPart(), 
                d1.toHoursPart(), 
                d1.toMinutesPart(), 
                d1.toSecondsPart()));
```

2 d 1h 6m 4s

Comment: How are you getting "toHoursPart" and above?

Answer (score 18):

## `org.threeten.extra.AmountFormats.wordBased`

The [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, which is maintained by Stephen Colebourne, the author of JSR 310, *java.time*, and *Joda-Time*, has an [`AmountFormats`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/AmountFormats.html) class which works with the standard Java 8 date time classes. It's fairly verbose though, with no option for more compact output.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(1).plusSeconds(9).plusMillis(86);
System.out.println(AmountFormats.wordBased(d, Locale.getDefault()));
```

`1 minute, 9 seconds and 86 milliseconds`

Comment: Wow, nice to know, I’ve not seen that feature. Has one major flaw though: Missing the [Oxford comma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: @BasilBourque The Oxford comma is typical for US, but interestingly not for UK. My lib Time4J (which has a far better internationalization) supports this distinction in the class [net.time4j.PrettyTime](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html) and also allows control over compact output if desired.

Comment: FYI, you can add an Oxford comma in ThreeTen-Extra by providing your own locale for the `wordbased` ResourceBundle, and overriding the `WordBased.spaceandspace` key. You could do this by putting a file named `org/threeten/extra/wordbased_ox.properties` on your ClassPath with contents `WordBased.spaceandspace=, and `. Then, if you use `Locale.forLanguageTag("ox")` the Oxford comma will be added automatically.

Source is here: https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/threeten/extra/

Answer (score 12):

Another Java 9+ solution:

```
private String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    long days = duration.toDaysPart();
    if (days > 0) {
        parts.add(plural(days, "day"));
    }
    int hours = duration.toHoursPart();
    if (hours > 0 || !parts.isEmpty()) {
        parts.add(plural(hours, "hour"));
    }
    int minutes = duration.toMinutesPart();
    if (minutes > 0 || !parts.isEmpty()) {
        parts.add(plural(minutes, "minute"));
    }
    int seconds = duration.toSecondsPart();
    parts.add(plural(seconds, "second"));
    return String.join(", ", parts);
}

private String plural(long num, String unit) {
    return num + " " + unit + (num == 1 ? "" : "s");
}
```

E.g.,

```
6 days, 21 hours, 2 minutes, 14 seconds
```

Comment: You can also use StringBuilder or StringJoiner

Comment: The whole inside a class with JUnit test code after modifications: https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/e2a0603a2eff556b37f4c07b20d193d3

Comment: what about yeah month day? `2 years 11 months 28 days`

Answer (score 11):

A **Java 8** version based on [user678573's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323209/103412):

```java
private static String humanReadableFormat(Duration duration) {
    return String.format("%s days and %sh %sm %ss", duration.toDays(),
            duration.toHours() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(duration.toDays()),
            duration.toMinutes() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(duration.toHours()),
            duration.getSeconds() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(duration.toMinutes()));
}
```

... since there is no PeriodFormatter in Java 8 and no methods like getHours, getMinutes, ...

I'd be happy to see a better version for Java 8.

Comment: throws java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Long

Comment: with Duration d1 = Duration.ofDays(0);
  d1 = d1.plusHours(47);
  d1 = d1.plusMinutes(124);
  d1 = d1.plusSeconds(124);
  System.out.println(String.format("%s days and %sh %sm %1.0fs", 
             d1.toDays(), 
             d1.toHours() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(d1.toDays()), 
             d1.toMinutes() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(d1.toHours()), 
             d1.toSeconds() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(d1.toMinutes())));

Comment: @erickdeoliveiraleal Thanks for pointing that out. I think I was originally writing the code for groovy, so it might have worked in that language. I corrected it for java now.

Comment: what about yeah month day? `2 years 11 months 28 days`

Answer (score 10):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) has a [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html) class that can represent such quantities, and can be rendered (via [`IsoPeriodFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISOPeriodFormat.html)) in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, e.g. `PT4D1H3M5S`, e.g.

```
Period period = new Period(millis);
String formatted = ISOPeriodFormat.standard().print(period);
```

If that format isn't the one you want, then [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) lets you assemble arbitrary layouts, including your C#-style `4d1h3m5s`.

Comment: Just as a note, `new Period(millis).toString()` uses the `ISOPeriodFormat.standard()` by default.

Answer (score 10):

Here's how you can do it using pure JDK code:

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;

long diffTime = 215081000L;
Duration duration = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(diffTime);

System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.getDays() * 24 + duration.getHours(), duration.getMinutes(), duration.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to the builder-approach of Joda-Time would be a **pattern-based solution**. This is offered by my library **Time4J**. Example using the class [Duration.Formatter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.Formatter.html) (added some spaces for more readability - removing the spaces will yield the wished C#-style):

```
IsoUnit unit = ClockUnit.MILLIS;
Duration<IsoUnit> dur = // normalized duration with multiple components
  Duration.of(123456, unit).with(Duration.STD_PERIOD);
Duration.Formatter<IsoUnit> f = // create formatter/parser with optional millis
  Duration.Formatter.ofPattern("D'd' h'h' m'm' s[.fff]'s'");

System.out.println(f.format(dur)); // output: 0d 0h 2m 3.456s
```

This formatter can also print durations of `java.time`-API (however, the normalization features of that type are less powerful):

```
System.out.println(f.format(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(123456))); // output: 0d 0h 2m 3.456s
```

The expectation of the OP that "123456 ms as a long would be printed as 4d1h3m5s" is calculated in an obviously wrong way. I assume sloppiness as reason. The same duration formatter defined above can also be used as parser. The following code shows that "4d1h3m5s" rather corresponds to `349385000 = 1000 * (4 * 86400 + 1 * 3600 + 3 * 60 + 5)`:

```
System.out.println(
  f.parse("4d 1h 3m 5s")
   .toClockPeriodWithDaysAs24Hours()
   .with(unit.only())
   .getPartialAmount(unit)); // 349385000
```

Another way is using the class `net.time4j.PrettyTime` (which is also good for localized output and printing relative times like "yesterday", "next Sunday", "4 days ago" etc.):

```
String s = PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(dur, TextWidth.NARROW);
System.out.println(s); // output: 2m 3s 456ms

s = PrettyTime.of(Locale.ENGLISH).print(dur, TextWidth.WIDE);
System.out.println(s); // output: 2 minutes, 3 seconds, and 456 milliseconds

s = PrettyTime.of(Locale.UK).print(dur, TextWidth.WIDE);
System.out.println(s); // output: 2 minutes, 3 seconds and 456 milliseconds
```

The text width controls if abbreviations are used or not. The list format can be controlled, too, by choosing the appropriate locale. For example, standard English uses the Oxform comma, while UK does not. The latest version v5.5 of Time4J supports more than 90 languages and uses translations based on the CLDR-repository (an industry standard).

Comment: this PrettyTime is way better than the one in the other answer! too bad I didn't find this first.

Comment: I don't know why there are now two downvotes for this well working solution so I have decided to extend the answer by giving more examples also about parsing (the opposite of formatting) and to highlight the wrong expectation of the OP.

Answer (score 9):

With Java 8 you can also use the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toString--) method of [`java.time.Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html.) to format it without external libraries using [ISO 8601 seconds based representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) such as PT8H6M12.345S.

Comment: Note that this does not print days

Comment: Not sure this format meets my definition of *pretty* print.  :-)

Comment: @james.garriss To make it a little prettier, see [the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754839/642706) by erickdeoliveiraleal.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this might not fit your use case exactly, but [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) might be useful here.

```
PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
System.out.println(p.format(new Date()));
//prints: “right now”

System.out.println(p.format(new Date(1000*60*10)));
//prints: “10 minutes from now”
```

Comment: Is it possible to have just "10 minutes" ?

Comment: Not an answer - the question was about the Duration type, not Date.

Answer (score 0):

naive kotlin version (avoiding `to*Part` functions, to work with Android)

```
fun prettyFormatSecondsToDuration(seconds: Long): String {
    val duration = java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)
    return buildString {
        val hours = duration.toHours()
        if (hours > 0) append("${hours}h ")

        val minutes = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes()
        if (minutes > 0) append("${minutes}m ")

        val partSeconds = duration.minusHours(hours).minusMinutes(minutes).seconds
        if (partSeconds > 0) append("${partSeconds}s ")
    }.trimEnd()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe the `toXxxPart` methods are available on Android through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).