# Count total Duration in terms of hours or minutes of two Dates

Tags: java, groovy

I'm new to groovy and currently working on manipulating dates. Is their anyway that I can subtract or add two dates in groovy? For example I have:

```
def build = Build.get(params.id)
def firstDate = build.firstDate
def secondDate = build.secondDate
```

now I want to add the dates something like:

```
firstDate + secondDate = (total hours or minutes)
```

....or does it need to be converted to something like integer?

Update:

For example, the start date is Jan.7,2013 12:00 and the end date is Jan.8,2013 1:30. I want to calculate how many hours or minute their is in between those dates...sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: What does it mean to add two dates?

Comment: I mean for example I want to add the total hours or minutes?

Comment: yeah adding dates doesn't make sense.. Adding a duration to a date does.. Subtracting dates makes sense.

Comment: sorry, just edited the title

Comment: *"I want to add the total hours or minutes"* what do you mean "total hours"? Since when we need to count them?

Comment: I want to count the total duration in terms of hours or minutes.

Comment: Could you tell us what is "duration" of todays date?

Comment: give example of input and output

Comment: For example, the start date is Jan.7,2013 12:00 and the end date is Jan.8,2013 1:30. I want to calculate how many hours or minute their is in between those dates...sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, the start date is Jan.7,2013 12:00 and the end date is
>   Jan.8,2013 1:30. I want to calculate how many hours or minute their is
>   in between those dates.

The following will give difference in milliseconds.

```
def diffdate = secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime();
```

Now use appropriate math to convert to hours and minutes.

e.g. diffdate / 60000 will give you minutes, diffdate / 3600000 will give you hours

Answer (score 2):

Using [TimeCategory](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html):

```
use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
   def duration = secondDate - firstDate
   println "Days: ${duration.days}, Hours: ${duration.hours}, Hours: ${duration.minutes}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`TimeCategory`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) category provides exactly what you're looking for :)

When using this category, java.util.Dates become much more user-friendly and let you do the things you'd expect them to do with very little code. For example, [subtracting two dates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html#minus%28java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date%29) and getting a [`TimeDuration`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html) as a result:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

// Using same dates as the question's example.
def start = Date.parseToStringDate('Mon Jan 07 12:00:00 GMT 2013')
def end = Date.parseToStringDate('Tue Jan 07 01:30:00 GMT 2013')

use (TimeCategory) {
    println start - end // Prints "10 hours, 30 minutes"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here:  Groovy can use Java Libraries.

That being the case, you should look into the JodaTime library.  It has a class named [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html).  The duration can take two [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) classes.  They are very similar to java Date's. [Here's how you can print out a duration in a pretty way.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471418/61624)  I'll inline the answer in the link for convenience:

```
Duration duration = new Duration(123456); // in milliseconds
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .appendDays()
     .appendSuffix("d")
     .appendHours()
     .appendSuffix("h")
     .appendMinutes()
     .appendSuffix("m")
     .appendSeconds()
     .appendSuffix("s")
     .toFormatter();
String formatted = formatter.print(duration.toPeriod());
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: this not an answer, but comment

Comment: oh, thats a lot. I thought it can be accomplish by just a couple or single line. But thanks,

Comment: Maybe groovy has a way to do it in a simpler way from Java.  I don't know anything about groovy, sorry.