# Time difference in Java

Tags: java

Why the output of the Java code below is 04:18:23 and not 03:18:23?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date start = sdf.parse("00:44:16");
        Date end = sdf.parse("04:02:39");
        long duration = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(duration);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your time zone?

Comment: prints 22:18:23 for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: My time zone is GMT+1. I tried to set different time-zones for the Calendar object (GMT+0, GMT-1 ...), but the result is the same.

Comment: @Vlad It won't be the same if you're setting the timezone on your `SimpleDateFormat` instance rather than your `Calendar` instance.

Comment: Don't use a library. Do it yourself by extracting hours, minutes, seconds out from Date with their methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's not how you get a duration.  Change your code to this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date start = sdf.parse("00:44:16");
            Date end = sdf.parse("04:02:39");
            long duration = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(duration);
            System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see it prints out `1969 12 31 19:18:23`.  That's a **date** not a duration.  Since you're skipping the date components when you print out your answer, it *appears* like it's printing out a duration, but it's really not.

To be frank, I don't know how to do this in java.  I just use the JodaTime library.  There's a class called [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) that makes this easy.  Here's a SO question that shows how to use it to print out the results any way you want: ["pretty print" duration in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471397/pretty-print-duration-in-java)

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and I get the following output: 1970 01 01 04:18:23

Comment: @Vlad probably because of a difference in our time zones.  The difference we got is irrelevant to my point: You're printing out a date, not a duration.

Comment: @tieTYT If you set the timezone to UTC, it will print the expect result. It's a huge hack, but it would work if the difference is less than 24h.

Comment: Given that dates are represented as offset from 1/1/1970, the conceptual difference between a date and an interval is rather blurred. As it has been pointed out, in the GMT timezone this is the correct answer.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti I don't feel comfortable with that.  He coincidentally could get the correct answer if he switched the timezones and didn't print the date.  But if he were testing with a difference in years, it wouldn't print the right thing.

Comment: I agree that it's better to use a library that does provide an explicit representation for intervals. Date arithmetic is indeed tricky.

Comment: @tieTYT I preferred to use Date objects because I can format the output with SimpleDateFormat, which is quite nice in my opinion.

Comment: @Vlad well it's called `SimpleDateFormat`, not `SimpleDurationFormat`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use JodaTime, it's pretty simple to compute the hours, minutes, and seconds from a duration in milliseconds:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  Date start = sdf.parse("00:44:16");
  Date end = sdf.parse("04:02:39");
  long durationMs = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

  final int oneHourMs = 3600000;
  final int oneMinuteMs = 60000;
  final int oneSecondMs = 1000;

  long hours = durationMs / oneHourMs;
  long minutes = (durationMs % oneHourMs) / oneMinuteMs;
  long seconds = (durationMs % oneMinuteMs) / oneSecondMs;

  System.out.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds); 
  // outputs: 03:18:23
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- You are cramming a time-of-day value into a date-time object.
- You are using notoriously troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day value without a date and without a time zone.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "00:44:16" ); 
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "04:02:39" );
```

The `Duration` represents a span of time not attached to the timeline.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( start , stop );
```