# Java: Create a Timer without a GUI

Tags: java, timer

I'm working on a IRC Twitch.tv BOT (PircBot) and i want to implement a !uptime chatcommand which will display how long the Stream is online.

I searched in google a Bit and i only found solutions which requires a GUI.

Can Some1 tell me what libraries are good to use or give me some exampel code?

I need to display seconds, minutes, hours, days.

First i thought about doing a normal timer which counts +1 all seconds but i think its easier and there are some proper functions to handle such "count"-timers, right?

Im fine with any hints!

thanks :)

Thats what i came up with now:

In my Main class, i got a timer which i call with:

```
utimecounttimer();
```

My Timer looks like this:

```
  public void utimecounttimer() {

        uptimetimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  if (isstreamlive == true){
                  UptimeCount.Uptimestart();
                  }else{
                      UptimeCount.Uptimestop();
                  }
              }
              }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

and then my UptimeCount Class is here:

```
public class UptimeCount {

    public static long startTime = 0;
    public static long  OnlineTimeMillis = 0;

    public static float OnlineTimeSec = 0;
    public static float  OnlineTimeMin = 0;
    public static float OnlineTimeHour = 0;
    public static float OnlineTimeDay = 0;



    public static void Uptimestart(){

        if(startTime == 0){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }else


        if(startTime != 0){
        OnlineTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
        OnlineTimeSec = OnlineTimeMillis /1000F;
        OnlineTimeMin = OnlineTimeMillis /(60*1000F);
        OnlineTimeHour = OnlineTimeMillis /(60*60*1000F);
        OnlineTimeDay = OnlineTimeMillis /(24*60*60*1000F);
        }


        System.out.println("Seconds"+OnlineTimeSec);
        System.out.println("Minutes"+OnlineTimeMin);
        System.out.println("Hours"+OnlineTimeHour);
        System.out.println("Days"+OnlineTimeDay);

    }



    public static void Uptimestop(){

        startTime = 0;
        OnlineTimeMillis = 0;       
        OnlineTimeSec = 0;
        OnlineTimeMin = 0;
        OnlineTimeHour = 0;
        OnlineTimeDay = 0;
    }


}
```

And then, last but not least il get the Infos in chat with the following line in my Main class:

```
if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!uptime")) {
    sendMessage(channel," Stream is running for: "+UptimeCount.OnlineTimeDay +" Days, "+UptimeCount.OnlineTimeHour +" Hours. "+UptimeCount.OnlineTimeMin +" Minutes and " +UptimeCount.OnlineTimeSec +" Seconds.");
}
```

I didnt test it yet but i think i have to format the ms output of the floats and then it should be working, right?

Comment: If you can use Guava, you have `StopWatch`

Comment: Why not write your custom thread which keeps on incrementing this time counter and have a helper method embedded in it which tells you the seconds, minutes, hours and days the timer was running? Have it set up as a Daemon thread, so that it isn't running when your main application isn't running, but running only when the main application is running.

Comment: Use the system clock to detect how much time has elapsed.  Use Joda library to get proper values to display.

Comment: Il take a look at it fge, thanks.  @Awesome so u say i should go with my thoughts on doing a simple +1 timer thing? if yes, i do not understand what u mean by "helper method" or running it as a daemon thread. im still pretty new to java =P

Comment: @ ted that wouldnt work. The Bot is online/running the whole time but it will connect automatic to the Stream as soon its online and right there it shoudl start counting so im not sure if i can tell the program to get the systemtime from that point then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to represent durations and times:

```
// at startup of the stream
DateTime startedAt = DateTime.now();

// later
Duration elapsed = new Duration(startedAt, DateTime.now());
```

And could use the solution described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471418/621923) to format your output, to get a human readable output (ie. "1 hours 2 minutes").

Please also check [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) since it has methods like `toStandardHours`, `toStandardMinutes` which can be used to display the total number of hours/minutes/etc. elapsed (ie. "1 hours | 62 minutes").

Comment: Ty, i will try this one out since the one i tried above doesnt work exactly as i need it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// it will give you  current time in mille seconds

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


// Mill second diffrence 

long  OnlineTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;


// time diff in mille seconds since  you are online 

float OnlineTimeSec = OnlineTimeMillis /1000F;

// time diff in Minutes  since  you are  online
float  OnlineTimeMin = OnlineTimeMillis /(60*1000F);

// time diff in Hours  since  you are online
float OnlineTimeHour = OnlineTimeMillis /(60*60*1000F);

// time diff in days  since  you are online  
float OnlineTimeDay = OnlineTimeMillis /(24*60*60*1000F);
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Thanks!  Im able to just put that stuff in a method so i can only call it as soon as the bot connects to the stream IRC when its live and start counting from there?

Comment: Keeping the above stuff in method and run in separate thread when users gets connected to stream @user3220962?

Comment: I guess so?  pack it into a static void xyz() so i can call that one as soon the bot connects each second since then so the floats getting updated or is my thinking on this one wrong?

Comment: update your question with your code @user3220962

Comment: gonan write it right now. just give me some minutes =)

Comment: Hey, i did edit the post above to your needs. Hope for an reply =)   Thanks in advise! Oh snap, it seems i tried to edit your post :o. im sorry! i just edited mine now. this site is a bit irritating for a beginner like me hehe