# Java String class replaceAll method missing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm having a very weird issue right now, the `replaceAll` method is missing from the `String` object.

JDK version: 1.8.0
Android Studio version: 3.1.3
Kotlin version: 1.2

[image]

[It hasn't been removed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), so whats going on here??

Comment: Java or JavaScript ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis Java

Comment: @HalayemAnis it's Kotlin. Kotlin is a JVM language, which means it uses Java API's (the reason it's tagged Java)

Comment: @daka That's a kotlin `String`, not a java `String`. Kotlin has just `replace`

Comment: The Kotlin [`replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) function can accept a `Regex` argument. It doesn't need `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can do this with just [`replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) in Kotlin:

```
"foo and foo".replace("foo", "bar") // "bar and bar"
```

Note that the call above replaces the literal strings, if you need a `Regex` as the first parameter you can do either of the following:

```
"foo and bar".replace("[abcd]".toRegex(), "x") // "foo xnx xxr"
"foo and bar".replace(Regex("[abcd]"), "x")    // "foo xnx xxr"
```

Comment: What do I do if I replace with `$1` like here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487511/2111778

Answer (score 19):

Kotlin has it's own String class. All the replace methods are just `replace`.

`replaceAll` in Java uses regex, so I assume your goal is using regex. To do this, just use a regex object when you pass to replace:

```
sb.toString().replace("your regex".toRegex(), "replacement");
```

If you don't have regex (and that's wrong), don't call `.toRegex()`:

```
sb.toString().replace("replace target", "replacement");
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin has replaceAll as replace:

[replace in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html)

```
actual fun String.replace(
oldChar: Char, 
newChar: Char, 
ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): String (source)
```

Returns a new string with all occurrences of oldChar replaced with newChar.