# Convert ISO 8601 duration to human-readable text in Kotlin

Tags: datetime, kotlin, iso

I have an [ISO duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) of ‘PT11M1S’ (from the YouTube API). I know it means 11 minutes and 1 second, but is there any way I can convert it automatically in Kotlin into text that makes sense to the user (instead of the ‘PT11M1S’ string)?

Thanks!

Comment: What format would you like it in?  Something like “11 minutes and 1 second” (i.e. in English text)?  Does it need to be localisable?

Comment: Are you targeting at least Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target: **Java 8+**

Use `java.time` to get a Duration object. There doesn't seem to be [a great formatting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3471397/2111778), and the `replaceAll` one [does not work on Kotlin Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50946133/2111778), so here is a Kotlin equivalent:

```
fun humanReadableDuration(s: String): String = java.time.Duration.parse(s).toString()
        .substring(2).toLowerCase().replace(Regex("[hms](?!\$)")) { "${it.value} " }

fun main() = println(humanReadableDuration("PT11M1S"))  // prints "11m 1s"
```

The Regex adds spaces after h/m/s but NOT if it's the end of the string to avoid a trailing space.

---

Target: **Any**

Since you start with a String already you could avoid the Duration object entirely:

```
fun humanReadableDuration(s: String): String = s.substring(2)
        .toLowerCase().replace(Regex("[hms](?!\$)")) { "${it.value} " }
```