# How to get human readable duration from milliseconds in Elasticsearch Painless language?

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-watcher

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487511/96588) doesn't work, just giving a "compile error" message in the watcher simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [AWS Elasticsearch disables regexes](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-replace-string-without-regexp-inside-painless-inline-script-for-aws-elasticsearch/110707) by default. The (so far untested, but compiles) solution avoiding regexes is `Duration.ofMillis(ctx.payload._source.computed.duration).toString().substring(2).replace("H", "h ").replace("M", "m ").replace("S", "s").trim()`.