# date difference in millis to localdatetime

Tags: java, android

I need to print date again after i calculated difference between two dates.

here is what I tried:

```
 fun getRemainingTime(endTime: ZonedDateTime): Long {
        val currentTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())

        return dateUtils.durationDifference(currentTime, endTime).toMillis()
    }
```

but when I try to convert it to localdate like below again it starts with `1970`. So I need to actual date which was calculated. **for example: difference between `2022-10-10` and `2022-10-12` should be `2022-10-02`**

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(remainingDurationInMillis), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not make sense. Say that you have calculated a difference of a minute so got 60000 milliseconds. This number does not imply any *actual date which was calculated*, neither in 1970 nor in 2022. And a `LocalDateTime` is for a date and time of day (not that often useful), not for an amount of time. For your difference one would use `java.time.Duration`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.time.LocalDateTime` was not created to represent a difference between two dates. There are `java.time.Period` and `java.time.Duration` that should be used for it ([see Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html)).

> A `Duration` measures an amount of time using time-based values
> (seconds, nanoseconds). A `Period` uses date-based values (years,
> months, days).

They both have a convenient `.between()` method, which you could use like this:

```
Duration diff = Duration.between(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()), endTime);
```

The reason why there are no combined classes to represent duration as years, months, days AND hours, minutes, seconds is that a day could be 24 or 25 hours depending on Daylight saving time. So

> A `Duration` of one day is exactly 24 hours long. A `Period` of one day, when added to a `ZonedDateTime`, may vary according to the time zone. For example, if it occurs on the first or last day of daylight saving time.

I would suggest you to use the `Duration` class and if you want to pretty print it, you have to do it manually like this (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487511/8629960)):

```
System.out.println(diff.toString()
            .substring(2)
            .replaceAll("(\\d[HMS])(?!$)", "$1 ")
            .toLowerCase());
```

This will print something like `370h 24m 14.645s`. If you want days, months and years, you would have to calculate them from seconds and print.

If you're using Java 9+ there are methods to get number of days, hours, minutes and seconds in the duration:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%sd %sh %sm %ss", 
            diff.toDaysPart(), 
            diff.toHoursPart(), 
            diff.toMinutesPart(), 
            diff.toSecondsPart()));
```

Comment: If a combined period with duration is truly needed, you’ll find one in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) with its [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html). But, as mentioned in Answer, combining those two concepts tends to be problematic in practice.