# Calculating days hours min sec between date and time of format Wednesday 02-October-2022 11:51:1 PM

Tags: java, date

I am new to Java. I have a requirement to calculate the number of days, hour, time, sec from a given date to today, current time.

For example, I am getting 2 fields from database: **Date** and **Time**.
**Date** field is in the format `Wednesday 02-October-2022` and **Time** field in the format `11:51:1 PM`

In my Java class, I am able to pass these 2 field in String format:

```
public String getLastRun(String failedDate, String failedTime)
{

}
```

`String failedDate, String failedTime` are the **Date** and **Time** I got from DB in above format.

Now the issue is I need to calculate the *number of days, hour, time, sec passed* from that Date and time taken as input.

So, if **current date** is `Thursday 02-November-2022` and time is `11:51:1 PM`, I can calculate the number of days, hour, time, sec passed.
Example: Output: `Last service failed 30 Days 12 hours 55 minutes 45 seconds`  Kind of output calculating the given Date and time field as input to this current Date and time?

So far, I have taken this **Date** and **Time** as input in this format of `Wednesday 02-October-2022` and `11:51:1 PM`  in the Java class, but I am still not sure about:

1. How to generate or fetch current Date and Time in this format in Java code?
2. How to calculate the *number of days, hour, time, sec passed* from the given format with current Date and Time?

I have checked these following links: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005861/calculate-days-between-two-dates-in-java-8#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20between,days%20which%20completed%2024%20hours.), [Link2](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-between-dates-in-java/) with local dates, but none of these have helped me to get the number of days, hour, time, sec from the given date and time format dynamically.
I even tried with SimpleDateFormat as mentioned [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java/) but not able to get with this format.

Any sample or pointer to start with will be helpful.
Pls Note: Time zone is IST Asia/Kolkata

Comment: Working here with IST time zone Asia/Kolkata

Comment: Those details belong in the Question, not the Comments.

Comment: edited the question.. added at the end

Comment: Assuming that date and time are stored as `date` and `time` in the database (as they should be), do not retrieve them as strings. Retrieve a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime` object so you do not have to parse them. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285553/dates-with-no-time-or-timezone-component-in-java-mysql).

Comment: Allow me to suggest you search a bit harder. This might be helpful, for example? [Difference Between Two Dates in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference). When you search, prefer the search results that use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) as do the two answers posted so far.

Answer (score 2):

Parse your date as a `LocalDate` using `DateTimeFormatter`. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Parse your time of day as a `LocalTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Specify your intended time zone.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Combine.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( date , time , zone ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`.

```
Instant then = zdt.toInstant () ;
```

Use `Duration` to calculate elapsed time on a scale of 24-hour long “days” (not calendar days), hours, minutes, seconds, and nanos.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( then , Instant.now() ) ;
```

---

The ideal solution would be educating the publisher of your data on using standard ISO 8601 formats.

---

Comment: I am very new to this. Some more details or reference will be helpful.

Comment: @ShashankRaj Search Stack Overflow to learn more. Your Question is a duplicate of others. And study [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) by Oracle, free of cost.

Comment: I am trying to get the output from this format which I am not getting from any tutorial or even stackoverflow. That's the reason I asked to give some more details so that I can take it forward. I am trying to understand from your answer

Comment: For formatting the result use your search engine. Among many results I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471397/how-can-i-pretty-print-a-duration-in-java). And of course see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your steps should be as follows:

1. Parse the date string into `LocalDate` using the applicable `DateTimeFormatter`.
2. Parse the time string into `LocalTime` using the applicable `DateTimeFormatter`.
3. Create an instance of `LocalDateTime` using the instances of `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` obtained from the above steps.
4. Find the `Duration` between the obtained `LocalDateTime` and the current date-time.
5. Get the days, hours, minutes, seconds from the obtained `Duration`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test
    System.out.println(getLastRun("Wednesday 05-October-2022", "11:51:1 PM"));
  }

  public static String getLastRun(String failedDate, String failedTime) {
    LocalDateTime givenDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.parse(failedDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd-MMMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)),
        LocalTime.parse(failedTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH)));

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    Duration duration = givenDateTime.isAfter(now) ? Duration.between(now, givenDateTime)
        : Duration.between(givenDateTime, now);

    return String.format("Last service failed %d Days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds",
        duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Last service failed 27 Days 21 hours 27 minutes 49 seconds
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)** and about the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) through Q/As tagged with [duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java).