# Date with set fields gives arbitrary values every time it's invoked

Tags: java, android, date, greendao

I'm trying to work with dates in sqlite and I need a way of comparing them. My issue is that when I try to save a setup date into the database it gives me new values; They however don't differ much - just in milliseconds.

Here's the code:

```
Date today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
```

How do I make it to give me constant values ?

P.S. I could've divided it by 1000 and save but I use greenDao framework, which encapsulates the insertion logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

date = now.getTime();
```

new Date() allocates the current time returned by System.currentTimeMillis().
Which means you are not resetting milliseconds in your code.

Comment: I think midnight also would like to reset minutes and hours. Maybe you want to update the example.

Comment: I have made the change. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at [Java Date rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001384/java-date-rounding)

Basically the answers suggest using Apache commons-lang DataUtils. See http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/index.html and especially the truncate method:

> public static Date truncate(Date date,int field)
>
> ```
> Truncate this date, leaving the field specified as the most significant field.
>
> For example, if you had the datetime of 28 Mar 2002 13:45:01.231, if
> ```
>
> you passed with HOUR, it would return 28 Mar 2002 13:00:00.000. If
>   this was passed with MONTH, it would return 1 Mar 2002 0:00:00.000.