# How to round to nearest hour and minutes by incremment in JavaScript without using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, hour

**Expected Result**

**Round Off Time** : 15 min

Given Time 10:00 => Rounded to: 10:00

Given Time 10:13 => Rounded to: 10:15

Given Time 10:15 => Rounded to: 10:15

Given Time 10:16 => Rounded to: 10:30

Given Time 16:00 => Rounded to: 16:00

Given Time 16:12 => Rounded to: 16:15

Round Off Time varies based on user input

**MyCode**

```
var m = (((minutes + 7.5)/roundOffTime | 0) * roundOffTime) % 60;
var h = ((((minutes/105) + .5) | 0) + hours) % 24;
```

**Current Output**

Given time: 08:22 => Rounded to: 08:15

Given time: 08:23 => Rounded to: 08:30

Need round off time should be in increment order

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687047/javascript-round-time-up-nearest-5-minutes

Comment: @PhaniKumarM—nope, the OP has strings, not dates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take all minutes and divide by `15` for getting the whole quarter and multiply by `15` for the result. Then take hours and minutes and apply formatting. Return joined values.

```js
function roundMinutes(t) {
    function format(v) { return v < 10 ? '0' + v: v; }

    var m = t.split(':').reduce(function (h, m) { return h * 60 + +m; });
    
    m = Math.ceil(m / 15) * 15;
    return [Math.floor(m / 60), m % 60].map(format).join(':');
}

var data = ['10:00', '10:13', '10:15', '10:16', '16:00', '16:12', '16:55'];

console.log(data.map(roundMinutes));
```

Comment: *…showed amazing focus and adherence to basic KISS principle in not being distracted by Date manipulations and formatting…*

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789384/round-a-date-to-the-nearest-5-minutes-in-javascript):

```js
var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
var date = new Date();  //or use any other date
console.log(date);
var rounded = new Date(Math.round(date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff);
console.log(rounded);
```