# Android: How to round date to 00 of next hour

Tags: java, android, date

I want to round a `Date` object to the next whole hour. For example, 04:15 should be converted to 05:00.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001384/java-date-rounding)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use use the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to do this:

```
public Date roundToNextWholeHour(Date date) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: It was -2, then 3 -> 4 -> 3, so 3 downvotes. I would very much like to hear the cause. Is there something obvious we are missing?

Comment: @KennethClark OK, probably misclick.

Comment: what will be case if it is 12.00

Comment: It would be converted to 13.00, I think thats what the OP want? because he has not mentioned about this..

Answer (score 0):

```
fun roundDate(date: Date): Date {
        val minToMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(60)
        val roundAdd = minToMs - date.time % minToMs
        return Date(date.time + roundAdd)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to solve this issue:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes (d.getMinutes() + 60);
d.setMinutes (0);
```

Comment: Just so it's mentioned, `setMinutes` has been deprecated apparently since 1.1.

Comment: Yes that could also work, but `setMinutes` is deprecated and you also need to set seconds to 0...