# Round java.util.Date to end of day

Tags: java, date, java-8, java.util.date, apache-commons-dateutils

I want to round a `java.util.Date` object to the end of the day, e.g. rounding `2016-04-21T10:28:18.109Z` to `2016-04-22T00:00:00.000Z`.

I saw [*Java Date rounding*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001384/java-date-rounding), but wasn't able to find something compareable for the end of the day. It also is not the same as [*how to create a Java Date object of midnight today and midnight tomorrow?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow), because I don't want to create a new `Date` (midnight today or tomorrow), but the next midnight based on any given date.

Comment: But why? Apparenly you are using Java 8 so why not just use the new time API?

Comment: Because it's a very large project where I don't get to decide to use that.

Comment: So you can use 3rd party APIs but can't use the built-in JDK APIs? This is usually the other way around.

Comment: End of day in which time zone? You've given an example in UTC, but are you sure that's what you want? And why are you asserting one particular way of doing it (DateUtils) rather than just the effect you want to achieve? If I give an answer that doesn't use DateUtils, is that a problem?

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my question. I don't need to use `DateUtils`, that didn't make sense.

Comment: "I saw this, but wasn't able to find something compareable for the end of the day." - If you can round "down" then you can just add a day and you're done. Or am I missing something?

Comment: 2016-04-22T00:00:00.000Z - are you sure that this is _end_ of day 2016-04-21T10:28:18.109Z, why not 2016-04-21T23:59:59.999Z?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850874/how-to-create-a-java-date-object-of-midnight-today-and-midnight-tomorrow

Comment: Sure. When you have a `LocalDateTime` for example, you can call `.with(LocalTime.MAX);` and it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DateUtils.ceiling](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#ceiling(java.util.Date,%20int)) serves your purpose. Pass `Calendar.DATE` for field value.

Comment: This does exactly what I expected. And it's the shortest solution. Thank you.

Comment: for me, it's going to the start of the next date

Answer (score 1):

Given the documentation of `DateUtils`, I'm not sure I'd trust it with this.

Assuming you're only interested in a UTC day, you can take advantage of the fact that the Unix epoch is on a date boundary:

```
public static Date roundUpUtcDate(Date date) {
    long millisPerDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
    long inputMillis = date.getTime();
    long daysRoundedUp = (inputMillis + (millisPerDay - 1)) / millisPerDay;
    return new Date(daysRoundedUp * millisPerDay);
}
```

I would *strongly* urge you to move to the `java.time` API if you *possibly* can though.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way

```
@Test
public void testDateRound() throws ParseException {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2016-04-21T10:28:18.109Z");
    System.out.println(date);
    Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
    cl.setTime(date);
    cl.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cl.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cl.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cl.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    System.out.println(cl.getTime());
    cl.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
    System.out.println(cl.getTime());
}
```

Output

```
Thu Apr 21 10:28:18 GMT+03:00 2016
Thu Apr 21 23:59:59 GMT+03:00 2016
Fri Apr 22 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2016
```