# How to update Date() every second?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to make a program that updates currentTime every second so that in the console it will go 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    OSpanel runner = new OSpanel();
    runner.currentTime();
}

public static void currentTime() throws InterruptedException{
    if(true) {
        Date currentTime = new Date();
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(currentTime);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(currentTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count time from the start of the application...

Comment: Or round it to the nearest second? [Java Date rounding - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001384/java-date-rounding)

Comment: Unrelated, but what is `if(true)` supposed to do? Also, your currentTime function shouldn't be static if you want to use it as an instance method

Answer (score 4):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

You can use [`Instant#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) to get the current instant of time. In order to get it every second, you can use [`ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
            .scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                () -> System.out.println(Instant.now()), 
                0, 
                1,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            );
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2021-10-03T13:53:42.462768Z
2021-10-03T13:53:43.469758Z
2021-10-03T13:53:44.470316Z
...
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/A1eRwJ)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline, normally represented in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) time. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note:** If you want to print just the running second, replace the print statement with the following:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).getSecond() + "s")
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: Good Answer, as per usual. I would suggest adding a mention of shutting down the executor service eventually. And for smooth incrementing by single seconds, I would schedule the task for every half-second or every 700 milliseconds or so. Scheduling by full seconds might see the displayed value slipping from 5 to 7 seconds while skipping 6, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `currentTime` outside of the while loop - you are outputting the date to the console every second but you are not updating the time.

Try this:

`Main.java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    OSpanel runner = new OSpanel();
    runner.currentTime();
}
```

`OSpanel.java`

```
public void currentTime() throws InterruptedException{
        int counter = 1;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(counter + "s");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't print "1s,2s,3s", though

Comment: I'm not sure what OP really wants in terms of output.

Comment: "so that in the console it will go 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s and so on" seems very explicit to me

Comment: Edited, I know that's explicit but what happens after 60 seconds? Does OP want minutes and hours? I can read.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a thread pool with one thread which will execute the lambda printing the number of seconds since the program started once every second.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SOAnswer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println(String.format("%ds", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000)), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's better to explain why

Answer (score 0):

## `Duration`

Adding to the good [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69425557/642706), let me show the use of [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to track elapsed time.

Record a starting moment.

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

At any other moment, calculate elapsed time on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds using the [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Generate text representing that elapsed time in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` .

```
String output = Duration.toString() ;
```

> PT21s

To generate text in a custom format, write a method that accesses the various parts. Call [`toHoursPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHoursPart()), `toMinutesPart`, etc. Put those parts together in whatever way you desire.

Pulling this all together, in the code of that other Answer, change this line:

```
() -> System.out.println( Instant.now() ) ,
```

… to this line:

```
() -> System.out.println( Duration.between( start , Instant.now() ).toString() ) ,
```

… or call your custom formatting method.