# Why can't I get a duration in minutes or hours in java.time?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Of the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class in the new [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) date API ([java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) available in Java 8 and later, the javadoc says :

> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds and
>   nanoseconds. **It can be accessed using other duration-based units, such
>   as minutes and hours**.In addition, the DAYS unit can be used and is treated as exactly equal to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight savings effects.

So, why does the following code crash ?

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(3000);
System.out.println(duration.get(ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
```

This raises an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` :

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Minutes
    at java.time.Duration.get(Duration.java:537)
```

So what is the recommended way to extract minutes and hours from a duration object ? Do we have to make the calculation ourselves from the number of seconds ? Why was it implemented that way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827047/formatting-a-duration-in-java-8-jsr310 (the not-accepted answer)

Comment: FYI, there is a project to extend java.time, [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/). But I don't think it presently has anything to help you.

Comment: Seems that JSR 310 java.time is not all that we hoped. It is not a complete and superior replacement for [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). While java.time has its strengths, so does Joda-Time. Joda-Time offers three classes for handling a span of time (Duration, Period, Interval), has good built-in support for ISO 8601 string representation of spans, and good support for defining your own formatters.

Comment: Yeah, I was still using the old Date API, waiting for the 310, but now I am thinking, will I go with Joda instead. But the 310 API is still so much better than the old Date one!

Comment: @PierreHenry Fortunately, we can use *both* java.time and Joda-Time, applying either in the case where its strengths have merit. Just be careful with your `import` statements as they share a few common class names (`LocalDate` etc.). For clarity, I suggest never mixing java.time and Joda-Time in the same chunk of code. As for those old `java.util.Date` & `.Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat`, definitely avoid them.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

"Why was it implemented that way?"

Other answers deal with the `toXxx()` methods that allow the hours/minutes to be queried. I'll try to deal with the why.

The `TemporalAmount` interface and `get(TemporalUnit)` method was added fairly late in the process. I personally was not entirely convinced that we had enough evidence of the right way to work the design in that area, but was slightly arm-twisted to add `TemporalAmount`. I believe that in doing so we slightly confused the API.

In hindsight, I believe that `TemporalAmount` contains the right methods, but I believe that `get(TemporalUnit)` should have had a different method name. The reason is that `get(TemporalUnit)` is essentially a framework-level method - it is not designed for day-today use. Unfortunately the method name `get` does not imply this, resulting in bugs like calling `get(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` on `Duration`.

So, the way to think of `get(TemporalUnit)` is to imagine a low-level framework viewing the amount as a `Map<TemporalUnit, Long>` where `Duration` is a `Map` of size two with keys of `SECONDS` and `NANOS`.

In the same, way, `Period` is viewed from the low-level frameworks as a `Map` of size three - `DAYS`, `MONTHS` and `YEARS` (which fortunately has less chance of errors).

Overall, the best advice for application code is to ignore the method `get(TemporalUnit)`. Use `getSeconds()`, `getNano()`, `toHours()` and `toMinutes()` instead.

Finally, one way to get "hh:mm:ss" from a `Duration` is to do:

```
LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plus(duration).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
```

Not pretty at all, but it does work for durations less than one day.

## New `to…Part` methods in Java 9

[JDK-8142936](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142936) issue now implemented in Java 9, adding the following methods to access each part of a `Duration`.

- `toDaysPart`
- `toHoursPart`
- `toMinutesPart`
- `toSecondsPart`
- `toMillisPart`
- `toNanosPart`

Comment: Thanks for the interesting insider view on the why, and the useful little formatting trick :)

Comment: Difference between `toDays` and `toDaysPart`? Documentation is the same. Is it just because for other units like hours and minutes it make sense to have both methods, so they also added two methods for days with the same effect?

Answer (score 38):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) says:

> This returns a value for each of the two supported units, SECONDS and NANOS. All other units throw an exception.

So, best guess answer -- that's the way they designed it.

You can use some of the other methods to get it in [hours](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toHours--):

```
long hours = duration.toHours();
```

or [minutes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes--):

```
long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
```

Comment: Interesting. I actually didn't see those toXXX methods. But they convert the total number of seconds to a number of the required unit, without taking into account the superior units. E.g : for a duration of `10000` seconds, the `toMinutes()` method will return 166. Not so useful if you need do display `hh:mm:ss`, but can be used as part of a more complete calculation method.

Comment: @PierreHenry Well, it's not exactly in the format you want, but you can use `duration.toString()` to get the duration as a human-readable value

Comment: To get just the hours component (without the days): `int hours = (int) ( duration.toHours() % 24L );`

Answer (score 14):

To get the hour/minute/second components in a "normalised" way, you need to calculate them manually - the code below is essentially copied from the `Duration#toString` method:

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(3000);
long hours = duration.toHours();
int minutes = (int) ((duration.getSeconds() % (60 * 60)) / 60);
int seconds = (int) (duration.getSeconds() % 60);
System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

Comment: I can't find a  [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) API to do this.  So I follow this answer.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add to bigt's answer (+1) that pointed out the useful `toHours`, `toMinutes` and other conversion methods. The [Duration specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) says:

> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds and nanoseconds. [...]
>
> The range of a duration requires the storage of a number larger than a long. To achieve this, the class stores a long representing seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second, which will always be between 0 and 999,999,999.

There are a variety of **getter** methods such as `getSeconds`, `getNano`, and `get(TemporalUnit)`. Given that a duration is represented as a (seconds, nanos) pair, it's clear why `get(TemporalUnit)` is restricted to seconds and nanos. These getter methods extract data directly from the duration instance and are lossless.

By contrast, there is a variety of to-methods including `toDays`, `toHours`, `toMillis`
`toMinutes`, and `toNanos` that do **conversion** on the duration value. These conversions are lossy in that they involve truncation of data, or they might throw an exception if the duration value cannot be represented in the requested format.

It's clearly part of the design that the get-methods extract data without conversion and the to-methods perform conversions of some sort.

Answer (score 5):

Remove Hourse then get minutes

`long hours   = attendanceDuration.toHours();
long minutes = attendanceDuration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();`

Answer (score -1):

By below code i got this duration output:

> **1 day, 2 hours, 5 minutes**

code example:

```
private String getDurationAsString(Duration duration)
{
    StringBuilder durationAsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (duration.toDays() > 0)
    {
        String postfix = duration.toDays() == 1 ? "" : "s";
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(duration.toDays() + " day");
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(postfix);
    }

    duration = duration.minusDays(duration.toDays());
    long hours = duration.toHours();
    if (hours > 0)
    {
        String prefix = Utils.isEmpty(durationAsStringBuilder.toString()) ? "" : ", ";
        String postfix = hours == 1 ? "" : "s";
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(prefix);
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(hours + " hour");
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(postfix);
    }

    duration = duration.minusHours(duration.toHours());
    long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
    if (minutes > 0)
    {
        String prefix = Utils.isEmpty(durationAsStringBuilder.toString()) ? "" : ", ";
        String postfix = minutes == 1 ? "" : "s";
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(prefix);
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(minutes + " minute");
        durationAsStringBuilder.append(postfix);
    }

    return durationAsStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**Explanation**:

By using Duration interface you can easily find the exact String display you want.
you just need to reduce the bigger TemporalUnit from current duration.

for example:

1. calculate days
2. reduce days from duration
3. calculate hours
4. reduce hours from duration
   etc... until u get duration = 0

Comment: Which 'Utils' are you using?

Comment: @Atom999
Just using my prive "Utils" class to check if string is null or empty, nothing special