# Duration does not support DAYS contrary to class documentation

Tags: java, duration, java-time

In the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework of Java 8 and later, the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class says:

> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds and nanoseconds. It can be accessed using other duration-based units, such as minutes and hours. In addition, the [`DAYS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS) unit can be used and is treated as exactly equal to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight savings effects.

Yet when I call the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method and pass [`ChronoUnit.DAYS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS), an exception is thrown.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of ( 0 , 0 , 0 ); // First moment of the day.
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of ( 2 , 0 , 0 ); // 2 AM.

Duration duration = Duration.between ( start , stop );
long days = duration.get ( ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Days

Am I misunderstanding something, or misusing the classes?

Comment: As far as I remember the only ``ChronoUnit`` constants that work in ``Duration.get(...)`` are ``SECONDS`` and ``NANOS`` but I never found out why.

Comment: @f1sh Why? It is because of the inner state of `Duration` which only holds seconds and nanoseconds. The `get(TemporalField)`-method is designed to yield a **partial** amount according to the inner state. In contrast, `toDays()` tries to determine the **whole** amount converted to days on base 1d=24h.

Comment: I have a typo in my previous comment. Instead of saying `get(TemporalField)` I wanted to say: `get(TemporalUnit)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get(TemporalUnit)` method is unfortunately confusing and not intended for most users. To understand why, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491243/why-cant-i-get-a-duration-in-minutes-or-hours-in-java-time/24500045#24500045).

Java SE 9 will include a much richer set of access methods for `Duration`. For now, you can use `toDays()` to get the total number of days.

The Javadoc is not exactly wrong, but maybe not perfectly helpful. The class does have some support for days of 24 hours in the `toDays()`, `ofDays(), plusDays()` etc. It is just that the `get(TemporalUnit)` method is very misleadingly named (should be `internalGet(TemporalUnit)` or some such name).

Answer (score 6):

Documentation for `get` on the Duration class.

> Gets the value of the requested unit.
>   This returns a value for each of the two supported units, SECONDS and NANOS. All other units throw an exception.

However, the `Duration` class has a method called `toDays`:

> Gets the number of days in this duration.
>   This returns the total number of days in the duration by dividing the number of seconds by 86400. This is based on the standard definition of a day as 24 hours.

Comment: So the class documentation is in error, and I should file a bug report?

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't think this is a bug, but maybe just slightly confusing documentation. The overall class description just gives a summary. I'd consider method descriptions to trump the overall summary. It doesn't explicitly say *where* you can use `DAYS`, but if you read some of the other methods (like `minus`) you can use `DAYS` in those cases.

Comment: I expended the doc quote. Sure seems to me that we should be able to get a number of days.

Answer (score 0):

**A.** It's better to replace

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0); // First moment of the day.
```

with

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.MIN; // First moment of the day.
```

or with

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT; // First moment of the day.
```

Also, the following

```
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of ( 2 , 0 , 0 ); // 2 AM.
```

can be replaced with

```
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of ( 2 , 0 ); // 2 AM.
```

**B.** The exception that you have encountered is the expected behaviour and is already documented at [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

> This returns a value for each of the two supported units, SECONDS and
> NANOS. All other units throw an exception.

You can get the list of supported units using [`Duration#getUnits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getUnits--) which unfortunately has been declared as a non-static function (and therefore you will have to create an arbitrary duration in order to use it):

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ofDays(10);// An arbitrary duration
        System.out.println(duration.getUnits());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Seconds, Nanos]
```