# Convert minutes to hours scala

Tags: scala, localdate

I have a number in `minutes`, for example:

```
Int totalminutes= 342
```

I want to dispaly it like this:

```
5h:42m:..s
```

I did a scala function to convert the minute to hour and return `HH:MM:SS`

```
scala> def convertSeconds(input:Int):String ={
     | val totalMinutes = input/60
     | val seconds = input%60
     | val minutes = totalMinutes%60
     | val hours   = totalMinutes%60
     |
     | return "%sh:%sm:%ss".format(hours,minutes,seconds)
     | }
convertSeconds: (input: Int)String
```

I did my tests:

```
scala> convertSeconds(120) // 120 minutes
res22: String = 2h:2m:0s  // why it add 2 minutes

scala> convertSeconds(60) // 60 minutes
res23: String = 1h:1m:0s  // adding 1 minute

scala> convertSeconds(36)  // 36 minutes
res24: String = 0h:0m:36s   // I want to return 0h:30m:06s
```

The solution is:

```
scala> def convertSeconds(input:Int):String ={
//val totalMinutes = input/60
//val seconds = input/60%60
val minutes = input%60
val hours   = input/60
return "%sh:%sm".format(hours,minutes)
}
convertSeconds: (input: Int)String

scala> convertSeconds(36)
res57: String = 0h:36m

scala> convertSeconds(120)
res58: String = 2h:0m

scala> convertSeconds(122)
res59: String = 2h:2m

scala> convertSeconds(2166)
res60: String = 36h:6m
```

Comment: You calculate minutes and hours with the same formula, so you'll get the same number.

Comment: I edited my question thank you

Comment: If a method converts `36` to `0h:36m`, it probably should be called `convertMinutes`...

Comment: @vero - You answered your question in the question. The desired approach on SO would be to self-answer the question.

Comment: I recommend you find some inspiration here: [Why can't I get a duration in minutes or hours in java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491243/why-cant-i-get-a-duration-in-minutes-or-hours-in-java-time) (the answer is you can)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you need a separate function to achieve this.
Scala already gives a [library](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/duration/Duration.html) to do that

```
scala> val secs = 62
secs: Int = 62

scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> val inTime = Duration(secs,SECONDS)
inTime: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 62 seconds

scala> "%02d:%02d:%02d".format(inTime.toHours,inTime.toMinutes%60,inTime.toSeconds%60)
res8: String = 00:01:02
```

EDIT-1: What this does not handle is if you pass a number >= 86400 (total seconds in a day)

Comment: `62` === `00:01:62`? I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have updated the answer. Also, this approach does not handle number > 86400 (total seconds in a day)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is supposed to be like this and you pass seconds not minutes:

```
def convertSeconds(input:Int):String ={
       val hours   = input/3600
       val minutes = (input-hours*3600)/60
       val seconds = input%3600-minutes*60
       "%sh:%sm:%ss".format(hours,minutes,seconds)
     }
```

If you want to pass `minutes`, the function should be something like this, I named it `convertMinutes`, and your seconds will `zero`, and you can get in your prescribed display by this code:

```
def convertMinutes(input:Int):String ={
        val hours   = input/60
        val minutes = input-hours*60
        "%sh:%sm:%ss".format(hours,minutes,"..")
    }
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> convertSeconds(7523)
res4: String = 2h:5m:23s


scala> convertSeconds(9523)
res5: String = 2h:38m:43s

scala> convertSeconds(3724)
res6: String = 1h:2m:4s


scala> convertMinutes(342)
res10: String = 5h:42m:..s
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, trusting you to translate yourself:

```
    int totalminutes = 342;
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMinutes(totalminutes);
    String display = String.format("%dh:%02dm:%02ds",
            dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart(), dur.toSecondsPart());
    System.out.println(display);
```

This prints:

> 5h:42m:00s

If had a number of seconds instead, use `Duration.ofSeconds` instead.

Don’t do the calculation yourself. It’s error-prone and it will require your reader to take some time to convince herself/himself that your calculation is correct. Instead let the library methods do the calculations, even when they seem trivial.

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s been said already: You used

```
 val hours   = totalMinutes%60
```

This should have been a division:

```
 val hours   = totalMinutes / 60
```

It’s easier than you might expect to make such an error. For comparison you don’t that easily call `toMinutesPart` when you intended `toHours`, and if you still do, it’s easier to spot the bug.

Comment: I will always prefer to do it this way.